# Determine project root from a running node.js application

Tags: node.js, working-directory

Is there a different way, other than `process.cwd()`, to get the pathname of the current project's root-directory. Does Node implement something like ruby's property, `Rails.root`,. I'm looking for something that is constant, and reliable.

Answer (score 877, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this, each with their own pros and cons:

### `require.main.filename`

From http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html:

> When a file is run directly from Node, `require.main` is set to its `module`. That means that you can determine whether a file has been run directly by testing `require.main === module`
>
> Because `module` provides a `filename` property (normally equivalent to `__filename`), the entry point of the current application can be obtained by checking `require.main.filename`.

So if you want the base directory for your app, you can do:

```js
const { dirname } = require('path');
const appDir = dirname(require.main.filename);
```

#### Pros & Cons

This will work great most of the time, but if you're running your app with a launcher like **pm2** or running **mocha** tests, this method will fail. This also won't work when using Node.js ES modules, where `require.main` is not available.

### `module.paths`

Node publishes all the module search paths to `module.paths`.  We can traverse these and pick the first one that resolves.

```js
async function getAppPath() {
  const { dirname } = require('path');
  const { constants, promises: { access } } = require('fs');
  
  for (let path of module.paths) {
    try {
      await access(path, constants.F_OK);
      return dirname(path);
    } catch (e) {
      // Just move on to next path
    }
  }
}
```

#### Pros & Cons

This will sometimes work, but is not reliable when used in a package because it may return the directory that the package is installed in rather than the directory that the application is installed in.

### Using a global variable

Node has a global namespace object called `global` — anything that you attach to this object will be available everywhere in your app. So, in your `index.js` (or `app.js` or whatever your main app
file is named), you can just define a global variable:

```js
// index.js
var path = require('path');
global.appRoot = path.resolve(__dirname);

// lib/moduleA/component1.js
require(appRoot + '/lib/moduleB/component2.js');
```

#### Pros & Cons

Works consistently, but you have to rely on a global variable, which means that you can't easily reuse components/etc.

### `process.cwd()`

This returns the current working directory. Not reliable at all, as it's entirely dependent on what directory the process was launched **from**:

```bash
$ cd /home/demo/
$ mkdir subdir
$ echo "console.log(process.cwd());" > subdir/demo.js
$ node subdir/demo.js
/home/demo
$ cd subdir
$ node demo.js
/home/demo/subdir
```

### app-root-path

To address this issue, I've created a node module called **[app-root-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-root-path)**. Usage is simple:

```js
const appRoot = require('app-root-path');
const myModule = require(`${ appRoot }/lib/my-module.js`);
```

The **[app-root-path](https://github.com/inxilpro/node-app-root-path)** module uses several techniques to determine the root path of the app, taking into account globally installed modules (for example, if your app is running in `/var/www/` but the module is installed in `~/.nvm/v0.x.x/lib/node/`). It won't work 100% of the time, but it's going to work in most common scenarios.

#### Pros & Cons

Works without configuration in most circumstances. Also provides some nice additional convenience methods (see project page). The biggest con is that it won't work if:

- You're using a launcher, like pm2
- **AND**, the module isn't installed inside your app's `node_modules` directory (for example, if you installed it globally)

You can get around this by either setting a `APP_ROOT_PATH` environmental variable, or by calling `.setPath()` on the module, but in that case, you're probably better off using the `global` method.

### NODE_PATH environmental variable

If you're looking for a way to *determine* the root path of the current app, one of the above solutions is likely to work best for you. If, on the other hand, you're trying to solve the problem of loading app modules reliably, I highly recommend looking into the `NODE_PATH` environmental variable.

Node's [Modules system](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) looks for modules in a variety of locations.  [One of these locations is wherever `process.env.NODE_PATH` points](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders). If you set this environmental variable, then you can `require` modules with the standard module loader without any other changes.

For example, if you set `NODE_PATH` to `/var/www/lib`, the the following would work just fine:

```js
require('module2/component.js');
// ^ looks for /var/www/lib/module2/component.js
```

A great way to do this is using `npm`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=. node app.js"
  }
}
```

Now you can start your app with `npm start` and you're golden. I combine this with my [enforce-node-path](https://github.com/inxilpro/enforce-node-path) module, which prevents accidentally loading the app without `NODE_PATH` set. For even more control over enforcing environmental variables, see [checkenv](https://github.com/inxilpro/node-checkenv).

**One gotcha:** `NODE_PATH` **must** be set **outside** of the node app. You cannot do something like `process.env.NODE_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname)` because the module loader caches the list of directories it will search before your app runs.

**[added 4/6/16]** Another really promising module that attempts to solve this problem is [wavy](https://github.com/kolodny/wavy).

Comment: this yield's the mocha bin directory for me: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin`. What am I missing?

Comment: @Kevin in this case, mocha is the entry point of your application.  This is just an example of why finding the "project root" is so difficult--it depends so much on the situation and what you mean by "project root."

Comment: @inxilpro I suppose; I was just running a unit test against an app that happened to be started by mocha. I was hoping to get at the project root, whereever it happened to be installed, not the root directory of the program running the project.

Comment: @Kevin I completely understand.  My point is just that the concept of "project root" is **much** easier for a _human_ to understand than a _computer_.  If you want a fool-proof method, you need to configure it.  Using `require.main.filename` will work _most_ of the time, but not _all_ of the time.

Comment: @Kevin I doubt you're still following this, but see my latest update—the `app-root-path` module should help.

Comment: Tangentially related: this is an incredibly clever way to organize your Node project so that you don't have to worry about this problem so much: http://allanhortle.com/2015/02/04/store-your-client-code-in-node_modules.html

Comment: @inxilpro that link is awesome, it works with SailsJS, just creating the `node_modules` folder inside `api/controllers`. Then you can simply `require` it without any path and works

Comment: I don't know if there was a change in pm2 or a change with Node.js but `require.main.filename` appears to work with pm2. Don't know about mocha.

Comment: `path.parse(process.mainModule.filename).dir`

Comment: So i understand using `global` isnt normally a good thing to do but for defining the root directory or other simple strings wouldnt `global.App = {root:__dirname}` in the main file do the job that way i can just do `App.root` anywhere?

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua There's nothing inherently wrong with it—it just makes your code a little more fragile because now you're relying on a specific global to be set. It's become an implicit dependency—something that probably will break some day and may be trickier to debug.

Comment: From the root directory of the application I'm quite a fan of `global.__root = path.resolve(__dirname)` as it conforms to the same double underscore and makes it easy to identify and search for everywhere else.

Comment: Why do you use `path.resolve` here `path.resolve(__dirname);`. How is it different from `__dirname` ?

Comment: @faressoft that's a good point. There really shouldn't be a difference. In some cases, like when using webpack to compile a node library for the web, `__dirname` may not be an absolute path—but that shouldn't really matter here.

Comment: `"start": "NODE_PATH=. node app.js"` results in the literal `.` being returned inside the app for me. I had to use:

`NODE_PATH=$PWD` to get the actual path in `process.env.NODE_PATH`

Comment: Does anyone have a reliable solution that will work when hosted to Heroku and or AWS beanstalk?
The npm scripts NODE_PATH=  is great but only works for localhost

Comment: Similar to the global variable solution I prefer setting an environmental variable: `process.env.NODE_ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname);` works the same, but doesn't clutter the code. Perhaps you can include it.

Comment: For the time being, Unfortunately WebStorm IDE cannot detect path.join(global.appRoot, str) if str is typo, as well as not showing path suggestion

Comment: Since v11.14.0 there is also a handy `require.main.path` which seems to work the same as `path.dirname(require.main.filename)`.

Comment: The `node_modules/` directory is _always_ located on the root directory of the project. I've seen somewhere another solution which would recursively `cd ..` until it found the dir `node_modules/`, hence the app root directory. Can you comment on that solution?

Comment: @João Pimentel Ferreira there are lots of edge cases where the `node_modules` directory isn't in the root, so that's not safe—especially in a package where you don't know exactly how it'll be installed.

Comment: What about the file package.json ? Is not always at the root? In which edge cases is it not?

Answer (score 95):

`__dirname` isn't a global; it's local to the current module so each file has its own local, different value.

If you want the root directory of the running process, you probably do want to use `process.cwd()`.

If you want predictability and reliability, then you probably need to make it a requirement of your application that a certain environment variable is set. Your app looks for `MY_APP_HOME` (Or whatever) and if it's there, and the application exists in that directory then all is well. If it is undefined or the directory doesn't contain your application then it should exit with an error prompting the user to create the variable. It could be set as a part of an install process.

You can read environment variables in node with something like `process.env.MY_ENV_VARIABLE`.

Comment: If used with caution, this could work pretty well. But it would give different results when doing `bin/server.js` vs `cd bin && server.js`. (assuming these js files are marked being executable)

Comment: Using `process.cwd()` has worked like a charm for me, even when running mocha tests. Thank you!

Answer (score 59):

Simple:

```js
require('path').resolve('./')
```

Comment: ["If, after processing all given path segments, an absolute path has not yet been generated, the current working directory is used."](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths). This is just a roundabout way of doing `process.cwd()`.

Comment: This does not work when running the node application from outside the root folder!

Answer (score 45):

the easiest way to get the global root (*assuming you use NPM to run your node.js app 'npm start', etc*)

```
var appRoot = process.env.PWD;
```

*If you want to cross-verify the above*

Say you want to cross-check `process.env.PWD` with the settings of you node.js application. if you want some runtime tests to check the validity of `process.env.PWD`, you can cross-check it with this code (that I wrote which seems to work well). You can cross-check the name of the last folder in appRoot with the npm_package_name in your package.json file, for example:

```
    var path = require('path');

    var globalRoot = __dirname; //(you may have to do some substring processing if the first script you run is not in the project root, since __dirname refers to the directory that the file is in for which __dirname is called in.)

    //compare the last directory in the globalRoot path to the name of the project in your package.json file
    var folders = globalRoot.split(path.sep);
    var packageName = folders[folders.length-1];
    var pwd = process.env.PWD;
    var npmPackageName = process.env.npm_package_name;
    if(packageName !== npmPackageName){
        throw new Error('Failed check for runtime string equality between globalRoot-bottommost directory and npm_package_name.');
    }
    if(globalRoot !== pwd){
        throw new Error('Failed check for runtime string equality between globalRoot and process.env.PWD.');
    }
```

you can also use this NPM module: `require('app-root-path')` which works very well for this purpose

Comment: This works great on (most) unix systems. As soon as you want your npm module/app to work on Windows, `PWD` is undefined and this fails.

Comment: `process.cwd()`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer why would `process.cwd()` always be the same as project root?

Comment: if you call it in root file then it'd be

Answer (score 26):

As simple as adding this line to your module in the root, usually it is `app.js` or `app.ts`.

```
global.__basedir = __dirname;
```

Then _basedir will be accessible to all your modules.

**Note:** For typescript implementation, follow the above step and then you will be able to use the root directory path using `global.__basedir`

Comment: simple, easy and effective

Comment: is there any way to typescript type this? otherwise i need to put `ts-ignore` everywhere `__basedir` is referenced. a bit like adding extra fields to the `window` scope...

Answer (score 21):

Try traversing upwards from `__dirname` until you find a `package.json`, and decide that's the app main root directory your current file belongs to.

According to [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/npm/what-is-the-file-package-json/)

> The package.json file is normally located at the root directory of a Node.js project.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

function getAppRootDir () {
  let currentDir = __dirname
  while(!fs.existsSync(path.join(currentDir, 'package.json'))) {
    currentDir = path.join(currentDir, '..')
  }
  return currentDir
}
```

Comment: That's the best solution, indeed! Every NPM project by default has only a single unique `package.json` always located on the project root directory.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work, because some app is deployed to `.next` folder which happens to have a `package.json` file. However this logic does hold, so i just need to find an unique file to our app.

Answer (score 20):

I've found this works consistently for me, even when the application is invoked from a sub-folder, as it can be with some test frameworks, like Mocha:

```js
process.mainModule.paths[0].split('node_modules')[0].slice(0, -1);
```

Why it works:

At runtime node creates a registry of the full paths of all loaded files. The modules are loaded first, and thus at the top of this registry. By selecting the first element of the registry and returning the path before the 'node_modules' directory we are able to determine the root of the application.

It's just one line of code, but for simplicity's sake (my sake), I black boxed it into an NPM module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-root.pddivine

Enjoy!

**EDIT:**

`process.mainModule` is [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_mainmodule) as of v14.0.0

Use `require.main` instead:

`require.main.paths[0].split('node_modules')[0].slice(0, -1);`

Comment: `process.mainModule` [deprectaed since: v14.0.0](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_mainmodule) - use `require.main.paths[0].split('node_modules')[0].slice(0, -1);` instead.

Comment: What happens if you have more than one node_modules folder, as is the case with Electron apps

Comment: The `node_modules/` directory is _always_ located on the root directory of the project. That's the reason this works

Comment: shows deprecated

Answer (score 20):

**Preamble**

This is a very old question, but it seems to hit the nerve in 2020 as much as back in 2012.
I've checked all the other answers and could not find the following technique mentioned (it has its own limitations, but the others are not applicable to every situation either):

**Git + child process**

If you are using Git as your [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control), the problem of determining the project root can be reduced to (which I would consider the proper root of the project - after all, you would want your VCS to have the fullest visibility scope possible):

> retrieve repository root path

Since you have to run a CLI command to do that, we need to spawn a child process. Additionally, as project root is highly unlikely to change mid-runtime, we can use the synchronous version of the `child_process` module at startup.

I found [`spawnSync()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) to be the most suitable for the job. As for the actual command to run, [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) (with a `--porcelain` option for ease of parsing) is all that is needed to retrieve the absolute path of the root.

In the sample at the end of the answer, I opted to return an array of paths because there might be [multiple worktrees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/11407695) (although they are likely to have common paths) just to be sure. Note that as we utilize a CLI command, `shell` option should be set to `true` (security shouldn't be an issue as there is no untrusted input).

**Approach comparison and fallbacks**

Understanding that a situation where VCS can be inaccessible is possible, I've included a couple of fallbacks after analyzing docs and other answers. The proposed solutions boil down to (excluding third-party modules & packages):

| Solution | Advantage | Main Problem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [`__filename`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v17.x/docs/api/modules.html#__filename) | points to module file | relative to module |
| [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v17.x/docs/api/modules.html#__dirname) | points to module dir | same as `__filename` |
| `node_modules` tree walk | nearly guaranteed root | complex tree walking if nested |
| `path.resolve(".")` | root if CWD is root | same as `process.cwd()` |
| [`process.argv\[1\]`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v17.x/docs/api/process.html#processargv) | same as `__filename` | same as `__filename` |
| `process.env.INIT_CWD` | points to `npm run` dir | requires `npm` && CLI launch |
| `process.env.PWD` | points to current dir | relative to (is the) launch dir |
| [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v17.x/docs/api/process.html#processcwd) | same as `env.PWD` | `process.chdir(path)` at runtime |
| [`require.main.filename`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v17.x/docs/api/modules.html#requiremain) | root if `=== module` | fails on `require`d modules |

From the comparison table above, the following approaches are the most universal:

- `require.main.filename` as an easy way to get the root if `require.main === module` is met
- `node_modules` tree walk proposed [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61430183/11407695) uses another assumption:

> if the directory of the module has `node_modules` dir inside, it is likely to be the root

For the main app, it will get the app root and for a module — its project root.

**Fallback 1. Tree walk**

My implementation uses a more lax approach by stopping once a target directory is found as for a given module its root is the project root. One can chain the calls or extend it to make the search depth configurable:

```js
/**
 * @summary gets root by walking up node_modules
 * @param {import("fs")} fs
 * @param {import("path")} pt
 */
const getRootFromNodeModules = (fs, pt) =>

    /**
     * @param {string} [startPath]
     * @returns {string[]}
     */
    (startPath = __dirname) => {

        //avoid loop if reached root path
        if (startPath === pt.parse(startPath).root) {
            return [startPath];
        }

        const isRoot = fs.existsSync(pt.join(startPath, "node_modules"));

        if (isRoot) {
            return [startPath];
        }

        return getRootFromNodeModules(fs, pt)(pt.dirname(startPath));
    };
```

**Fallback 2. Main module**

The second implementation is trivial:

```js
/**
 * @summary gets app entry point if run directly
 * @param {import("path")} pt
 */
const getAppEntryPoint = (pt) =>

    /**
     * @returns {string[]}
     */
    () => {

        const { main } = require;

        const { filename } = main;

        return main === module ?
            [pt.parse(filename).dir] :
            [];
    };
```

**Implementation**

I would suggest using the tree walker as the preferred fallback because it is more versatile:

```js
const { spawnSync } = require("child_process");
const pt = require('path');
const fs = require("fs");

/**
 * @summary returns worktree root path(s)
 * @param {function : string[] } [fallback]
 * @returns {string[]}
 */
const getProjectRoot = (fallback) => {

    const { error, stdout } = spawnSync(
        `git worktree list --porcelain`,
        {
            encoding: "utf8",
            shell: true
        }
    );

    if (!stdout) {
        console.warn(`Could not use GIT to find root:\n\n${error}`);
        return fallback ? fallback() : [];
    }

    return stdout
        .split("\n")
        .map(line => {
            const [key, value] = line.split(/\s+/) || [];
            return key === "worktree" ? value : "";
        })
        .filter(Boolean);
};
```

**Disadvantages**

The most obvious one is having Git installed and initialized which might be undesirable/implausible (side note: having Git [installed on production servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846167/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-have-git-repository-in-production-server) is not uncommon, nor is it [unsafe](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45452/is-using-git-for-deploying-a-bad-practice)). Can be mediated by fallbacks as described above.

Answer (score 16):

All these "root dirs" mostly need to resolve some virtual path to a real pile path, so may be you should look at `path.resolve`?

```
var path= require('path');
var filePath = path.resolve('our/virtual/path.ext');
```

Answer (score 10):

## There is an `INIT_CWD` property on `process.env`.  This is what I'm currently working with in my project.

```
const {INIT_CWD} = process.env; // process.env.INIT_CWD 
const paths = require(`${INIT_CWD}/config/paths`);
```

Good Luck...

Comment: Worked like a charm for a package that manipulate the project it is being called from as a postinstall step. I have however not yet tested it in another layer of dependency, where a project uses a dependency that uses my package.

Comment: @JamesDev, `INIT_CWD` resolves to the `directory` from which the `npm-script` was exectued.

Comment: @Aakash, `require` doesn't work with ESM, but I succeeded to get a root just with `process.env.INIT_CWD`.

Answer (score 6):

A technique that I've found useful when using express is to add the following to app.js before any of your other routes are set

```
// set rootPath
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.rootPath = __dirname;
  next();
});

app.use('/myroute', myRoute);
```

No need to use globals and you have the path of the root directory as a property of the request object.

This works if your app.js is in the root of your project which, by default, it is.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, i find the perhaps trivial solution also to most robust:
you simply place the following file at the root directory of your project: root-path.js which has the following code:

```
import * as path from 'path'
const projectRootPath = path.resolve(__dirname)
export const rootPath = projectRootPath
```

Comment: `__dirname` is not defined in ES modules (`"type": "module"` in the `package.json`).

Answer (score 4):

Add this somewhere towards the start of your main app file (e.g. app.js):

```
global.__basedir = __dirname;
```

This sets a global variable that will always be equivalent to your app's base dir. Use it just like any other variable:

```
const yourModule = require(__basedir + '/path/to/module.js');
```

Simple...

Answer (score 4):

I know this one is already too late. 
But we can fetch root URL by two methods

1st method

```
var path = require('path');
path.dirname(require.main.filename);
```

2nd method

```
var path = require('path');
path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename);
```

Reference Link:- https://gist.github.com/geekiam/e2e3e0325abd9023d3a3

Answer (score 3):

> `process.mainModule` is [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_mainmodule) since v 14.0.0. When referring to the answer, please [use](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module) `require.main`, the rest still holds.

```
process.mainModule.paths
  .filter(p => !p.includes('node_modules'))
  .shift()
```

Get all paths in main modules and filter out those with "node_modules",
then get the first of remaining path list. Unexpected behavior will not throw error, just an `undefined`.

Works well for me, even when calling ie `$ mocha`.

Answer (score 2):

At top of main file add:

```
mainDir = __dirname;
```

Then use it in any file you need:

```
console.log('mainDir ' + mainDir);
```

- `mainDir` is defined globally, if you need it only in current file - use `__dirname` instead.
- main file is usually in root folder of the project and is named like `main.js`, `index.js`, `gulpfile.js`.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to determine project root from a running node.js application you can simply just too.

```
process.mainModule.path
```

Comment: ```[tsserver 6385] 'mainModule' is deprecated```

Answer (score 1):

### Make it sexy .

```
const users = require('../../../database/users'); //  what you have
// OR
const users = require('$db/users'); //  no matter how deep you are
const products = require('/database/products'); //  alias or pathing from root directory
```

#### Three simple steps to solve the issue of ugly path.

1. Install the package: `npm install sexy-require --save`
2. Include `require('sexy-require')` once on the top of your main application file.

   ```
   require('sexy-require');
   const routers = require('/routers');
   const api = require('$api');
   ...
   ```
3. Optional step. Path configuration can be defined in `.paths` file on root directory of your project.

   ```
   $db = /server/database
   $api-v1 = /server/api/legacy
   $api-v2 = /server/api/v2
   ```

Comment: Seems decent, too bad it had such a ridiculous name.

Comment: @JHH well... I had to find a better name

Answer (score 1):

It work for me

```
process.env.PWD
```

Answer (score 1):

This will step down the directory tree until it contains a `node_modules` directory, which usually indicates your project root:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

function getProjectRoot(currentDir = __dirname.split(path.sep)) {
  if (!currentDir.length) {
    throw Error('Could not find project root.')
  }
  const nodeModulesPath = currentDir.concat(['node_modules']).join(path.sep)
  if (fs.existsSync(nodeModulesPath) && !currentDir.includes('node_modules')) {
    return currentDir.join(path.sep)
  }
  return this.getProjectRoot(currentDir.slice(0, -1))
}
```

It also makes sure that there is no `node_modules` in the returned path, as that means that it is contained in a nested package install.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a function in app.js**

`/*Function to get the app root folder*/`

```
var appRootFolder = function(dir,level){
    var arr = dir.split('\\');
    arr.splice(arr.length - level,level);
    var rootFolder = arr.join('\\');
    return rootFolder;
}

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(appRootFolder(__dirname,1),'views'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this.

For my module named `mymodule`

`var BASE_DIR = __dirname.replace(/^(.*\/mymodule)(.*)$/, '$1')`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the root directory path in the express app variable and get this path from the app. For this add `app.set('rootDirectory', __dirname);` in your index.js or app.js file. And use `req.app.get('rootDirectory')` for getting the root directory path in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, however no question mention to use `progress.argv`. The argv array includes a full pathname and filename (with or without .js extension) that was used as parameter to be executed by node. Because this also can contain flags, you must filter this.

This is not an example you can directly use (because of using my own framework) but I think it gives you some idea how to do it. I also use a cache method to avoid that calling this function stress the system too much, especially when no extension is specified (and a file exist check is required), for example:

```
node myfile
```

or

```
node myfile.js
```

That's the reason I cache it, see also code below.

---

```
function getRootFilePath()
{
        if( !isDefined( oData.SU_ROOT_FILE_PATH ) )
        {
            var sExt = false;

            each( process.argv, function( i, v )
            {
                 // Skip invalid and provided command line options
                if( !!v && isValidString( v ) && v[0] !== '-' )
                {
                    sExt = getFileExt( v );

                    if( ( sExt === 'js' ) || ( sExt === '' && fileExists( v+'.js' )) )
                    {

                        var a = uniformPath( v ).split("/"); 

                         // Chop off last string, filename
                        a[a.length-1]='';

                         // Cache it so we don't have to do it again.
                        oData.SU_ROOT_FILE_PATH=a.join("/"); 

                         // Found, skip loop
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }, true ); // <-- true is: each in reverse order
        }

        return oData.SU_ROOT_FILE_PATH || '';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the root path of an electron app could get tricky. Because the root path is different for the main process and renderer under different conditions such as production, development and packaged conditions.

I have written a npm package [electron-root-path](https://github.com/ganeshrvel/npm-electron-root-path/) to capture the root path of an electron app.

```
$ npm install electron-root-path

or 

$ yarn add electron-root-path


// Import ES6 way
import { rootPath } from 'electron-root-path';

// Import ES2015 way
const rootPath = require('electron-root-path').rootPath;

// e.g:
// read a file in the root
const location = path.join(rootPath, 'package.json');
const pkgInfo = fs.readFileSync(location, { encoding: 'utf8' });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
path.join(...process.argv[1].split(/\/|\\/).slice(0, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename);
```

Comment: `process.mainModule` was deprecated in favor of `require.main`. (and if you're using ES6 modules, neither of these will work...)

Answer (score 0):

In modern versions of npm, you can add an entry to `exports`, to use as a shorthand. Note that if you want to be able to reference both the root itself and files within that root, you'll need both `./` and `./*` respectively:

`package.json`:

```
{
  "imports": {
    "#root": "./",
    "#root/*": "./*",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

`./index.js`:

```
import {namedExport} from '#root/file.js'
```

`./file.js`:

```
export const namedExport = {
  hi: "world",
};
```

Then:

```
$ node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node index.js
```

---

You could extend this further with a `constants.js` file, where you may use one of the methods in the above answers, or input an absolute path, should you require the path itself

Answer (score 0):

You can also use
`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
Assuming you are working on a git repository

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and reliable solution would be to `cd ..` recursively searching for `package.json`, considering that this file is always on the project root directory.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

function getAppRootDir () {
  let currentDir = __dirname
  while(!fs.existsSync(path.join(currentDir, 'package.json'))) {
    currentDir = path.join(currentDir, '..')
  }
  return currentDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const __root = `${__dirname.substring(0, __dirname.lastIndexOf('projectName'))}projectName`
```

`

Answer (score -1):

Try `path._makeLong('some_filename_on_root.js');`

example:

```
cons path = require('path');
console.log(path._makeLong('some_filename_on_root.js');
```

That will return full path from root of your node application (same position of package.json)

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
 path.resolve("./") ... output is your project root directory
```

Comment: this works great!

    path.resolve(".")

works as well

Comment: That only gives the current directory, which may not be the root directory.

Answer (score -5):

__dirname will give you the root directory, as long as you're in a file that's in the root directory.

```
// ProjectDirectory.js (this file is in the project's root directory because you are putting it there).
module.exports = {

    root() {
        return __dirname;
    }
}
```

In some other file:

```
const ProjectDirectory = require('path/to/ProjectDirectory');
console.log(`Project root directory is ${ProjectDirectory.root}`);
```

Comment: So it doesn't give you the root directory.

Comment: What? It gives you the root directory. Try it. Are you not able to access JS files in your project's root directory for some reason? As long as you are, create a JS object and have it check __dirname. Guaranteed it will work.

Comment: @AndrewKoster __dirname does not give you root directory by design, because it provides you directory name of the current script. Moreover, It could be changed from script to script. If you have it the same as docroot, it just coincidence no more, and narrates only about one fact - you have app.js stored inside your docroot.

Comment: It's not a coincidence that this ProjectDirectory.js is at the root directory, if you *put it there on purpose*. It's a design feature of the working solution that I've posted.