# Mocha tests with extra options or parameters

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am writing test cases for my Node.js application using Mocha. The test cases need an API key as an extra input option or parameter. The API key is private, so I don't want to include it directly in the test files as everyone then can see it on GitHub. I know there are some options available for Mocha at:

http://mochajs.org/#usage

But is it possible to include some parameters to let testers specify their own API key for the test in the commandline? Such as:

```
./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha test/*.js --key YOUR_KEY
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I don't think Mocha itself supports passing extra parameters to your tests, but you could use environment variables:

```
env KEY=YOUR_KEY mocha test/*.js # assumes some sort of Unix-type OS.
```

And read them in your test files:

```
var key = process.env.KEY;
```

Comment: For multiple parameters `env KEY1=YOUR_KEY1 KEY2=YOUR_KEY2 mocha test`

Comment: in 2017 it is now possible, see my answer below

Comment: @danday74 the problem is not sharing sensitive information. I don't see how your solution works around that, because it means that certain files _still_ can't be checked in. Using environment variables passed on the command line prevents having to do that.

Answer (score 35):

One of the easiest ways to pass parameters similar to the process.argv[index] method mentioned in this thread is using the npm config variables. This allows you to see the variable name a little more clearly:

**test command:**

```
npm --somevariable=myvalue run mytest
```

**package.json:**

```
"scripts": {
"mytest": "mocha ./test.js" }
```

**test.js**

```
console.log(process.env.npm_config_somevariable) // should evaluate to "myvalue"
```

Comment: this solution seems quite nice as its using the npm facility. could you comment on how you might pass multiple arguments from the command line like this?

Comment: @roman: Have you tried `npm ---somevar=myval --anothervar = anotherVal run mytest` with `process.env.npm_config_somevar` and `process.env.npm_config_anothervar`?

Answer (score 34):

Take a look at the [optimist](https://github.com/substack/node-optimist) module by Substack and [nconf](https://github.com/flatiron/nconf.git) from flatiron. A lot of my tests depend on external parameters and the optimist and nconf modules makes it easy to load configuration options from a json file

In your test command pass the path to the config.json file

### test command

```
mocha test/api-test.js --config=/path/to/config.json --reporter spec
```

### api-test.js

```
var path = require('path')
var fs = require('fs')
var assert = require('assert')
var argv = require('optimist').demand('config').argv
var configFilePath = argv.config
assert.ok(fs.existsSync(configFilePath), 'config file not found at path: ' + configFilePath)
var config = require('nconf').env().argv().file({file: configFilePath})
var apiConfig = config.get('api')
var apiKey = apiConfig.key
```

### config.json

```
{
  "api": {
    "key": "fooKey",
    "host": "example.com",
    "port": 9000
  }
}
```

---

## Alternative

Another pattern I have been using recently is the [config](https://npmjs.org/package/config) module. You can specify a `./config/default.yml` file for running regularly and a `./config/test.yml` file for tests.

When running your test suite, export NODE_ENV=test and the config module will load `test.yml`

In your code it is easy to access the configuration object

```
var config = require('config')

// config now contains your actual configuration values as determined by the process.env.NODE_ENV
var apiKey = config.api.key
```

An easy way to set NODE_ENV=test is by running your tests with a makefile. Run all your tests via `make test`. To run a single test execute `make one NAME=test/unit/sample-test.js`

### Sample makefile

```
MOCHA?=node_modules/.bin/mocha
REPORTER?=spec
GROWL?=--growl
FLAGS=$(GROWL) --reporter $(REPORTER) --colors --bail

test:
        @NODE_ENV="test" \
        $(MOCHA) $(shell find test -name "*-test.js") $(FLAGS)

one:
        @NODE_ENV="test" \
        $(MOCHA) $(NAME) $(FLAGS)

unit:
        @NODE_ENV="test" \
        $(MOCHA) $(shell find test/unit -name "*-test.js") $(FLAGS)

integration:
        @NODE_ENV="test" \
        $(MOCHA) $(shell find test/integration -name "*-test.js") $(FLAGS)

acceptance:
        @NODE_ENV="test" \
        $(MOCHA) $(shell find test/acceptance -name "*-test.js") $(FLAGS)

.PHONY: test
```

Answer (score 27):

The other answers are limited in that they do not support code execution prior to running your test suite. They only support passing parameters.

**This answer supports code execution BEFORE your test suite is executed and is fully documented by mocha**

mocha docs: http://unitjs.com/guide/mocha.html#mocha-opts

create ./test/mocha.opts

```
--recursive
--reporter spec
--require ./server.bootstrap
--require ./test/test.bootstrap
```

create ./server.bootstrap.js

```
global.appRoot = require('app-root-path');
// any more server init code
```

create ./test/test.bootstrap.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV='test';
// any more test specific init code
```

finally in your server.js:

```
require('./server.bootstrap');
```

DONE!

The code in the server bootstrap will be executed prior to testing and server execution (npm start and npm test)

The code in the test bootstrap will only be executed prior to testing (npm test)

Thanks to @damianfabian for this one - see [How to initialise a global variable in unit test runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874060/how-to-initialise-a-global-variable-in-unit-test-runs/41875048#41875048)

Answer (score 20):

There's no supported way to do this with Mocha. the suggested way is to use a file (for instance config.json), require it, and let other people change it.

That being said, if you pass your key at the end of the commandline (after the file to test) and use -- it should be available using process.argv (if you don't use -- or it's not after a regular file name, then mocha will fail).

if you run `./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --reporter spec test.js --apiKey=someKey` , and test.js contains the code:

```
var assert = require("assert")
describe("testy", function () {
    it("shouldy", function (done) {
        var value;
        for (var index in process.argv) {
            var str = process.argv[index];
            if (str.indexOf("--apiKey") == 0) {
                value = str.substr(9);
            }
        }
        assert.equal(value,"someKey")
        done();
    })
})
```

the test should pass

Answer (score 16):

You can pass an argument to mocha test script using 'minimist' module. 
Install with `npm install minimist`

Terminal:

```
mocha test.js --config=VALUE
```

Mocha node script:

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
console.log('config', argv.config);
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple way, using process.argv that contain the command line args

```
$ mocha  -w test/*.js --KEY=YOUR_VALUE
```

Later, you can get `YOUR_VALUE` in your code:

```js
let LAST_PARAM = process.argv[process.argv.length-1]

let PARAM_NAME  = LAST_PARAM.split("=")[0].replace("--","")
let PARAM_VALUE = LAST_PARAM.split("=")[1]

console.log("KEY: ", PARAM_VALUE)
```

To see all `process.argv`:

```js
process.argv.forEach((value, index) => {
        console.log(`process.argv[${index}]: ${value}`);
})
```

Output:

```
$ mocha  -w test/*.js --KEY=YOUR_VALUE

KEY:  YOUR_VALUE
process.argv[0]: /usr/local/bin/node
process.argv[1]: /Users/pabloin/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha
process.argv[2]: -w
process.argv[3]: test/tt.js
process.argv[4]: test/tt2.js
process.argv[5]: --KEY=YOUR_VALUE

KEY:  YOUR_VALUE
process.argv[0]: /usr/local/bin/node
process.argv[1]: /Users/pabloin/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha
process.argv[2]: -w
process.argv[3]: test/tt.js
process.argv[4]: test/tt2.js
process.argv[5]: --KEY=YOUR_VALUE
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to understand for the people here if you call it ```mocha  -w test/*.js --KEY=YOUR_VALUE``` instead of ```--KEY=YOUR_KEY```?

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for newly introduced --parallel mode. It spawns new nodejs processes, and these args are not passed to them

Comment: @Xotabu4 do you know if there is a way of passing the args when in --parallel mode?

Comment: @DonCharlie you can use env variables

Answer (score 3):

I could send parameter thought mochaStream (require('spawn-mocha-parallel').mochaStream).

like:

```
var mochaStream = require('spawn-mocha-parallel').mochaStream;

var mocha = mochaStream({
    env: function(){
        return {yourParam: 'value'}
    }
});

return gulp.src('test/**/*-specs.js', {read: false})
    .pipe(mochaStream)
    .on('error', console.warn.bind(console));
```

Inside ..spec.js file

```
var yourParam = process.env.yourParam;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been reading quite some answers, most of them more complex than the actual solution has to be.

Let's say I have `config.yml` or `config.json`. In my case it's a YAML file.

First of all I install the `yamljs` dependency. It has a function called `load`.

Basically what I do:

`const YAML = require('yamljs');
 const ymlConfig = YAML.load('./config.yml');`

Then I go for:

`process.env.setting1 = ymlConfig.setting1;
 process.env.setting2 = ymlConfig.setting2;`

And of course - this is all done in your test file.

Answer (score 1):

if you are debugging/testing with Mocha sidebar (VS Code extension), just put it:

```
{
    "mocha.env": {
        "KEY": "YOUR_KEY",
        "MY_VARIABLE": "MY VALUE"
    }
}
```

at `.vscode/settings.json`

Comment: This solution is too tied to a specific tool.

Comment: yep, I guess I'm clear when I put conditional at the beginning the answer, I'm just giving complement/other options about the main reference. :)