# Pass arguments to program through mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I just started using [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) to test my site. My test runner expects some command-line arguments though. When I run

```
mocha mytest.js arg1 arg2
```

All the args to to mocha, not my mytest script. Is there a way to forward them along?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocha tests with extra options or parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144455/mocha-tests-with-extra-options-or-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mocha is going to think those are paths to test files/directories. Maybe use environment variables or a configuration file instead of command line arguments.