# how to run some initialization code with mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I know about `before`, `beforeEach`, `after` and `afterEach` but how do I run some code before ALL tests.

In other words I files like this

```
test
  test1.js
  test2.js
  test3.js
```

I run the tests with

```
mocha --recursive
```

I don't want to have to put a `before` in every test file. I need a `beforeAllTests` or a `--init=setup.js` or something that I can execute some JavaScript before any tests have been executed. In this particular case I have to configure my system's logging module before the tests run

Is there a way to call some init function that get executed before all tests?

Comment: write a module and require it everywhere? if this helps you i will post it as answer.

Comment: thanks but that's really no better than putting a `before` in every file.

Answer (score 5):

If only initialization code is required, then `mocha -r ./init` might be enough for you. even put it into `test/mocha.opts`

```
--require ./test/init
--ui tdd
```

But if you need teardown actions, there is a dilemma, for example:

```
var app = require('../app.js');
app.listen(process.env.WEB_PORT);

after(function(done) {
    var db = mongoskin.db(process.env.DB_URL, {safe:true});
    db.dropDatabase(function(err) {
        expect(err).to.not.be.ok();
        db.close(done);
    });
});
```

you'll get the error:

`ReferenceError: after is not defined`

I guess mocha hasn't been initialized itself while handling '--require'.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out recently in our node app:

1. reorganize test files as below (only one js file "bootstrap.js" under test/, and put all test files in sub folders):

   ```
      test
      ├──unit
      │  ├── test1
      │  ├── test2
      │  └── ...
      ├──integeration
      │  ├── test1
      │  ├── test2
      │  └── ...
      ├── bootstrap.js
      └── mocha.opts
   ```
2. put '--recursive' into mocha.opts
3. put your initialization code into bootstrap.js (global before/after works here!)

done.

Comment: Depends on the name of your file. In your case `bootstrap.js` starts with `b` so it's the first to be found by --recursive mocha.

Comment: This was my fave answer until I found my new approach - see my answer (which is the official mocha solution)

Answer (score 3):

This is the official mocha solution:

[Mocha tests with extra options or parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144455/mocha-tests-with-extra-options-or-parameters/41874640#41874640)

It allows you to define code that can be:

1 - Executed before npm start and npm test

2 - Executed before npm test only