# Mocha: create and finalize test programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I want to proxy test results running on other environment in real time.

Here is some pseudo code that I want to make real:

```
  var test = proxy.getCurrentTest(); 
  // => {slow: 200, timeout: 2000, duration: 235, result: 'error'};

  var tmpIt = it('test1', function(){
      this.slow(test.slow);
      this.timeout(test.timeout);
  });
  tmpIt.close({
      duration: test.duration,
      result: test.result
  });
  // this should make this test red in the output, 
  // because the `result` is not 'success'
```

Is it anyhow possible to set test's result and duration without "really" running it? And get all the visual mocha output to the terminal?

**edit:** this question is not about how to pass variables with the test results form the child process to the main process. it's already working for me.

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, you can set params via environment variables.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144455/mocha-tests-with-extra-options-or-parameters

Comment: no its not about, providing extra options at all

Comment: Looks like i get. You want to send comand to start tests from your main machine/site to other machine/site and print result?

Comment: If i'm right, there is idea. You can run server on your test-runner machine, and listen for some commands, for example - run test with name from body/url. Then, you can spawn child process: child.exec("mocha", ["params"], ...., save child stdout to variable and send it back to main server.

Comment: yes @NazarSakharenko that's the idea. With your solution am stuck at the same problem but now at the cli and not in js code. I can pass the all the variables form the child process to the main process. I don't know how to create a test at set its duration and outcome without running it, from those variables.

Comment: Can you provide more expanded example that you want to get?

Comment: @AlexeyB. i have added more comments to the code. what i want is actually very simple, I want to "fake" test results based on other results.

Comment: According to your words "this should make this test red in the output, because the `result` is not 'success'" ```expect(test.result).to.be.equal('success')```? Sorry i really want to help, but got no idea that is your problem

Comment: right, but it will ignore the duration, and i don't want to fake the duration with a setTimeout because that would mean the tests are twice as slow, first i have to wait for the actual test and then for the fake test.

Answer (score 3):

Hope I understood the requirements correctly. What I implemented is a test result forwarder to mocha that integrated into mocha.

To integrate with mocha this implementation describes a [custom mocha interface](https://mochajs.org/#interfaces) to proxy test results from tests executed in another environment.

To use this interface the `-u` argument has to be passed to mocha when running mocha

```
> mocha -u ./path/to/proxy-interface ...
```

Note that `./path/to/proxy-interface` is the path that mocha uses in a `require` call to require the interface module.

The proxy interface is responsible to expose a `proxyTest` function to the global context such as mocha's BDD interface does with `it`, invoke the passed function to get the test results and forward the test results while preserving the number of tests executed displayed by the test runner.

```
var Mocha = require('mocha');

var Suite = Mocha.Suite;
var Test = Mocha.Test;
var escapeRe = require('escape-string-regexp');

module.exports = function(suite) {
  var suites = [suite];

  suite.on('pre-require', function(context, file, mocha) {
    // A bit hacky since we require mocha internal common interface module
    var common = require('mocha/lib/interfaces/common')(suites, context);

    context.run = mocha.options.delay && common.runWithSuite(suite);

    context.proxyTest = function(title, fn) {
      var suite = suites[0];
      if (suite.pending) {
        fn = null;
      }
      var test = new ProxyTest(title, fn);
      test.file = file;
      suite.addTest(test);
      return test;
    };
  });
};

var Runnable = Mocha.Runnable;
var inherits = require('util').inherits;

function ProxyTest(title, fn) {
  Runnable.call(this, title, null);
  this.pending = !fn;
  this.type = 'test';
  this.body = (fn || '').toString();

  this.fn = fn;
}

inherits(ProxyTest, Runnable);

ProxyTest.prototype.run = function(done) {
  var proxiedTestResult = this.fn();

  this.duration = proxiedTestResult.duration;
  this.timedOut = this.timeout() > proxiedTestResult.timeout;

  done(proxiedTestResult.result);
};

ProxyTest.prototype.clone = function() {
  var test = new ProxyTest(this.title, this.fn);
  test.timeout(this.timeout());
  test.slow(this.slow());
  test.enableTimeouts(this.enableTimeouts());
  test.retries(this.retries());
  test.currentRetry(this.currentRetry());
  test.globals(this.globals());
  test.parent = this.parent;
  test.file = this.file;
  test.ctx = this.ctx;
  return test;
};
```

The code above overrides Mocha's `Runnable` run implementation and runs the passed function to get test results and sets the required fields in the `ProxyTest` interface to be compatible with mocha tests.

**Usage**

In your tests use the `proxyTest` global to register a new test with mocha

```
var proxy = {
  getErrorTestResult() {
    return {slow: 200, timeout: 2000, duration: 50, result: 'error'};
  },

  getTimeoutTestResult() {
    return {slow: 200, timeout: 2000, duration: 3000 };
  },

  getSlowTestResult() {
    return {slow: 200, timeout: 2000, duration: 235 };
  },

  getSuccessTestResult() {
    return {slow: 200, timeout: 2000, duration: 50 };
  }
}

proxyTest('error', proxy.getErrorTestResult);
proxyTest('timeout', proxy.getTimeoutTestResult);
proxyTest('slow', proxy.getSlowTestResult);
proxyTest('success', proxy.getSuccessTestResult);
```

**Output**

[image: Mocha Output]

**Implications**

The drawback of this approach is that a custom interface has to be passed to mocha **AND** that you cannot use mocha BDD vocabulary like `describe`. The second drawback can be eliminated if you "extend" (In this case: copy some code) the BDD interface of mocha:

```
var Mocha = require('mocha');
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var Suite = Mocha.Suite;
var Test = Mocha.Test;
var escapeRe = require('escape-string-regexp');

/**
 * BDD-style interface - extended with proxy functionality:
 *
 *      describe('Array', function() {
 *        describe('#indexOf()', function() {
 *          it('should return -1 when not present', function() {
 *            // ...
 *          });
 *
 *          it('should return the index when present', function() {
 *            // ...
 *          });
 *        });
 *      });
 *
 * @param {Suite} suite Root suite.
 */
module.exports = function(suite) {
  var suites = [suite];

  suite.on('pre-require', function(context, file, mocha) {
    // A bit hacky since we require mocha internal common interface module
    var common = require('mocha/lib/interfaces/common')(suites, context);

    context.before = common.before;
    context.after = common.after;
    context.beforeEach = common.beforeEach;
    context.afterEach = common.afterEach;
    context.run = mocha.options.delay && common.runWithSuite(suite);
    /**
     * Describe a "suite" with the given `title`
     * and callback `fn` containing nested suites
     * and/or tests.
     */

    context.describe = context.context = function(title, fn) {
      var suite = Suite.create(suites[0], title);
      suite.file = file;
      suites.unshift(suite);
      fn.call(suite);
      suites.shift();
      return suite;
    };

    /**
     * Pending describe.
     */

    context.xdescribe = context.xcontext = context.describe.skip = function(title, fn) {
      var suite = Suite.create(suites[0], title);
      suite.pending = true;
      suites.unshift(suite);
      fn.call(suite);
      suites.shift();
    };

    /**
     * Exclusive suite.
     */

    context.describe.only = function(title, fn) {
      var suite = context.describe(title, fn);
      mocha.grep(suite.fullTitle());
      return suite;
    };

    /**
     * Describe a specification or test-case
     * with the given `title` and callback `fn`
     * acting as a thunk.
     */

    var it = context.it = context.specify = function(title, fn) {
      var suite = suites[0];
      if (suite.pending) {
        fn = null;
      }
      var test = new Test(title, fn);
      test.file = file;
      suite.addTest(test);
      return test;
    };

    /**
     * Exclusive test-case.
     */

    context.it.only = function(title, fn) {
      var test = it(title, fn);
      var reString = '^' + escapeRe(test.fullTitle()) + '$';
      mocha.grep(new RegExp(reString));
      return test;
    };

    /**
     * Pending test case.
     */

    context.xit = context.xspecify = context.it.skip = function(title) {
      context.it(title);
    };

    /**
     * Number of attempts to retry.
     */
    context.it.retries = function(n) {
      context.retries(n);
    };

    context.proxyTest = function(title, fn) {
      var suite = suites[0];
      if (suite.pending) {
        fn = null;
      }
      var test = new ProxyTest(title, fn);
      test.file = file;
      suite.addTest(test);
      return test;
    };
  });
};

var Runnable = Mocha.Runnable;
var inherits = require('util').inherits;

function ProxyTest(title, fn) {
  Runnable.call(this, title, null);
  this.pending = !fn;
  this.type = 'test';
  this.body = (fn || '').toString();

  this.fn = fn;
}

inherits(ProxyTest, Runnable);

ProxyTest.prototype.run = function(done) {
  var proxiedTestResult = this.fn();

  this.duration = proxiedTestResult.duration;
  this.timedOut = this.timeout() > proxiedTestResult.timeout;

  done(proxiedTestResult.result);
};

ProxyTest.prototype.clone = function() {
  var test = new ProxyTest(this.title, this.fn);
  test.timeout(this.timeout());
  test.slow(this.slow());
  test.enableTimeouts(this.enableTimeouts());
  test.retries(this.retries());
  test.currentRetry(this.currentRetry());
  test.globals(this.globals());
  test.parent = this.parent;
  test.file = this.file;
  test.ctx = this.ctx;
  return test;
};
```