# foward slashes and backward slash are confusing

Tags: node.js

I keep seeing this error:

`Error: Cannot find module 'E:\LARRY\FDC\stesh\backend\routes/core/util'`
What i don`t understand is the the forward slash and back slash.

my code looks like this.

`const appRoot = __dirname + '/../../';
var util = require(__dirname + '/../../core/util');`

what could be the solution to the forward slash backward menace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backslashes are the platform specific delimiter for file paths on Windows, which is why `__dirname`will yield `E:\LARRY\FDC\stesh\backend\routes` in your case.

Note that when dealing with paths, you should always use the `path` module which will ensure cross-platform functionality for all the paths you want to access.

Also you should not pass a direct path to require but a relative path instead (see [Node require absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229944/node-require-absolute-path) for more details).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .replace function to swap all the path separators in the string.

```
const appRoot = (__dirname + '/../../').replace("\\","/");
```