# Angular2 - root relative imports

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a problem with imports in angular2/typescript. I'd like to use imports with some root like 'app/components/calendar', instead only way I am able to use is something like:

```
//app/views/order/order-view.ts
import {Calendar} from '../../components/calendar
```

where Calendar is defined like:

```
//app/components/calendar.ts
export class Calendar {
}
```

and this obviously gets much worse the lower in hierarchy you go, deepest is '../../..' but it is still very bad and brittle. Is there any way how to use paths relative to project root?

I am working in Visual Studio, and relative imports seem to be the only thing that makes VS able to recognize these imports.y

Comment: `"baseUrl"` maybe should set `"./src"` and `paths relate to it` wiil get it to work, it origin to be `"./"` , but my is not work, I don't know why! and then add `"paths": { "@app/*": ["app/*"] }` to `tsconfig.json` and use like `import { PageNotFoundComponent } from '@app/error-page/page-not-found.component';`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## **UPDATE**

Just don't use this solution. Embrace [node module resolution algorithm](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together).
Community rests on it, so everything will break apart if you try to do otherwise. Use aliases or some of the other provided solutions.

**Short answer**
There's a way but you shouldn't do it.
Set the compilerOption `"moduleResolution"` to `"classic"`.

**Long answer**

Are you using `tsconfig.json`? I assume you are. I've been looking a way to make statements such as `import someModule = require ("../../../../someModule"` into `import someModule=require("src/path/to/someModule")`.
I found after hours wasted that tsc may use different algorithms for module resolution. I'm using atom and it creates the `tsconfig.json` with the compilerOption property `moduleResolution` set to `"node"` and it uses the shitty (excuse my french) module resolution algorithm of node. I just put "classic" and started working the obvious way.

Comment: "classic" option completely breaks angular2, do you know any way how could this be fixed?

Comment: have your source files be in a folder named "node_modules". It is explained in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24461606/2142728

Comment: put all your code inside a folder called "node_modules"... that's the other option

Comment: thats the most possible worst option i have ever heard of @caeus

Comment: Do any of the 19 people that have so far upvoted @nottinhill have a better solution?

Comment: Embrace node resolution algorithm (not joking, it's, after dealing with it a log, not that bad). You can otherwise start using alias for your modules.

Comment: @Neutrino look at Mareks answer below

Answer (score 35):

## Answer

As of TypeScript 2.0 you can set tsconfig.json properties `baseUrl` as following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "app"
}
```

Then, you might use your desired manner of importing components, like:

```
import { Calendar } from 'components/calendar';
```

### Appendix

#### Fallback paths resolution

An important consideration is that specifying `baseUrl` option causes TypeScript compilator to:

1. Look up a path with regards to baseUrl
2. On failed resolution (module not found), look up a path with regards to `moduleResolution` option

#### SystemJS

Since SystemJS is heavily used in Angular development stage, be sure to accordingly config also `systemjs.config.js`, so that it resolves paths correctly.

---

Source and further details: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039

Comment: @MerekDulwski , I referenced your solution in a question where I have issues with it and TSLint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292139/typescript-tslint-tslint-not-recognizing-root-relative-imports-via-baseurl

Comment: I actually found this is NOT the ideal solution after I was having problems with it. I posted my new preferred solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51599367/1253298 Please give it a try.

Comment: Actually this is the same solution.
It's just the `baseUrl` option set to *root project directory* that makes it different from my suggestion, which, I agree, wasn't the best possible.

I'll update my answer, glad you have found the perfect solution.

Answer (score 13):

Basically, in `Angular 6` you can start the `import` from the **top** or **bottom**.

## My two options

They are available with default config generated by `angular CLI`

1. From the top
   I prefer this way if it's closer from the root of the app

   `import { DateService } from "src/app/shared-services/context/date.service";`
2. From the bottom

   `import { DateService } from "../../../../../../../shared-services/context/date.service";`

## Context:

TypeScript config: **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Angular's stack

`ng -v`

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.9.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8

@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.1
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Answer (score 7):

One way would be to have files that re export and bundle the files with a shorter path.

You could have a components.ts folder in the root of your application with.

```
export {Calendar} from './components/calendar'
export {*} from './components/map'
```

And importing it from **components**

```
import {Calendar, Map} from '../../components';
```

This however will is better suited to exporting modules so others can use them, than the way to structure a project.

The alternative would be to forgo the use of import statements and use internal modules instead.

calendar.ts

```
module Components {
    export class Calendar {}
}
```

And you will be able to just use it in any of the files in your projects like this.

```
new Components.Calendar();
```

Or import it with an alias.

```
import Calendar = Components.Calendar;
new Calendar();
```

Answer (score 5):

Tl;dr: you should now be able to use `src` as the root and it will "just work".

With Angular 2.0, when you run `ng new my-proj`, it auto-creates a file `my-proj/src/tsconfig.app.json`. This file contains a `baseUrl` line:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
```

Thus, you shouldn't have to change anything about your config and you can scope all of your imports rooted on `src`.  Assuming your project structure looks something like:

```
my-proj/
  README.md
  src/
    app/
      sidebar/
        sidebar.component.ts
      user.service.ts
```

you can import your files with:

```
import { Sidebar } from 'app/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { UserService } from 'app/user.service';
```

Edited to add: Sublime does not read `src/tsconfig.json`, though, it only reads the top-level tsconfig.json (see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin/issues/213)). If you're getting `Cannot find module 'app/...'` errors on your import lines in Sublime, you can add:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
```

to your top-level tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to change anything from the default configuration of a new Angular project generated from Angular-CLI. Not sure about previous versions, but as of version 6, I know this is true. To do a root-relative import, you use `src/` at the beginning of your imports like:

```
import { VideoPlayerComponent } from 'src/app/pages/shared/video-player/video-player.component';
```

This a better solution than @MarekDulowski's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42306860/1253298), because root-relative imports can be easily identifiable and easily found/searched for globally by querying `"src/`.

I learned this from the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51582699/1253298