# Angular 2 can you import something from the project root instead of having to go back using ../

Tags: angular, typescript, import

I've found that I'm slowly digging my own grave, because the deeper my folder structure gets, the further back I must go each time I need to import a module from my root component:

```
import {ComponentsModule, SharedModule} from '../../../../../../shared';
```

Since that view also have child views then it will become even longer.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614818/angular2-root-relative-imports) which suggests that this is not possible with Angular 2 as of now. Yet it seems so odd to me that there wouldn't be a way to achieve something like this instead:

```
import {ComponentsModule, SharedModule} from 'src/app/shared';
```

Is this a feature that will come in the future or is this already possible somehow?

**EDIT:** As per @Sasxa's suggestion I did this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

But now when I try to start Angular CLI I get a whole bunch of errors, main ones being these: `ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Recursion in resolving` and `ERROR in multi main Module not found: Error: Recursion in resolving`.

Is something missing?

Comment: I've been looking into this some months back and it was possible by making node module that exports stuff (kinda like you import from '@angular'). I found this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039, and it seams some options have been added to `tsconfig`. I'll have to look into it too (;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this could be done with `paths` and `baseUrl` compiler options from `tsconfig.json`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

Here's an example from docs:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                    "*",
                    "generated/*"
                ]
            }
    }
}
```

> This tells the compiler for any module import that matches the pattern "*" (i.e. all values), to look in two locations:
>
> - "*": meaning the same name unchanged, so map  => \
> - "generated*" meaning the module name with an appended prefix “generated”, so map  => \generated\

Should be available in TypeScript 1.9+

---

#### Update:

I just tried it: adding `"baseUrl": "."` allows me to `import {...} from 'app/shared'` anywhere in my app (my `tsconfig.json` is in the `src\` folder). Compiles without any errors and works with Angular CLI.

Comment: Yea, I just changed it in one file, the rest are still with `../../`

Comment: Try without paths, I just used `baseUrl`.

Comment: Ah, sick bro. This will help me out a ton! Wish I could upvote you x100 :D