# How to shorten path in import Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Sometimes I have to specify the full path to another service/component based on current component location like:

```
import {LocalService} from '../../../_services/LocaleService';
```

To agree that it is not convenient.

How to shorten this path to more beauty and elegant?

Comment: See this question [Angular2 - root relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614818/angular2-root-relative-imports)

Comment: You can add the paths to you tsconfig. See this. [How to use paths in tsconfig.json answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json#answer-43330003)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a matter of [style](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-guide). Consider restructuring your application to follow the [LIFT](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#lift) principle such that you can Locate code quickly, Identify the code at a glance, keep the Flattest structure you can, and Try to be DRY.

To keep the folder structure as flat as possible, take advantage of splitting your application into modules and utilize [folders by feature](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#folders-by-feature-structure).

Take a  look [here](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#overall-structural-guidelines) for a good example of folder structure.