# logic for the number of dots and slashes in importing class in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import

in angular I need to import files , class from another files to my file, class.. I am confused with dots and slashes, cant find any logic sometimes. Would you please help?

Comment: File paths are relative to the baseUrl in your compiler options. See this question for more about import paths: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614818/angular2-root-relative-imports

Comment: Is there any automat way to add it the the top of the file?

Comment: Yes, depending on the IDE you use. VS Code, for example: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_auto-imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ./

./ means moving back from current file.

*Example*

[image: find image here]

In above image I'm at test.component.ts, by using ./ I came out from that file and currently I'm at test folder.

### ../

../ means moving back from current folder.

*Example*

[image: find same image here]

by doing ./ I came out from the test.component.ts file after that i used ../ that means I came out from test folder. so ./../ help me to get out of test folder.

### /

/ means we are moving forward

*Example*

After ./../ I will be at src scope and I can directly move forward into app folder by adding / final path will be ./../app/

### Conclusion=>

/    (normal slash)           - moving forward

./   (slash with pre dot)     - moving back from file

../  (slash with 2 pre dots   - moving back from folder