# Don't ignore node_modules in Atom

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

I'm using `node_modules` to store my code, following the advice of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24630974/599184

However, Atom's search ignores `node_modules`. How can I get it to include `node_modules` in the search? I don't have `node_modules` in Atom's "ignored names" setting.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The default behavior in Atom is to ignore the folders and files in .gitignore

Two solutions:

- In Atom main settings, uncheck "Exclude VCS ignored Paths"

or

- When you do a project search, use *"node_modules"* as file/directory pattern if you are searching in the node_modules directory, or *"node_modules, src"* if you are searching in the node_modules directory and in your src folder, for example

Comment: `\`node_modules\`` doesn't work for me in the folder textbox, but `**/*` does

Comment: You've saved my time dude!

Answer (score 50):

I unchecked **Exclude VCS ignored paths** in main settings but it didn't work. So I did some research and I found out that there is another setting that overrides this.

The setting you need is found in

**Settings > Packages > Core Packages > Tree View**

Here you’ll find **Hide Ignored Names** and **Hide VCS Ignored Files** settings – the latter is the one you want to stop the sidebar from ignoring files that your VCS ignores.

[image: hide ignored elements]

Got this from the following source and it works for me:

[blog.lukebennett.com/2015/09/21/show-hidden-files-in-atom-sidebar](http://blog.lukebennett.com/2015/09/21/show-hidden-files-in-atom-sidebar)

Comment: That works for me, I guess this is a default behavior which cause hiding `node_modules` and other ignore stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this for newer versions:

**File > Config...**

```
    "*":
  core:
    excludeVcsIgnoredPaths: false <-- Set to false
    uriHandlerRegistration: "always"
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "****"
  "tree-view":
    hideVcsIgnoredFiles: false <-- Set to false
  welcome:
    showOnStartup: false
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Click within the tree-view pane.
2. Press `i` to toggle files and directories hidden by `.gitignore`.