# How to get VS Code intellisense to search multiple node_modules folders for typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, intellisense, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I have a node/typescript project structured like so:

```
- node_modules // => these are loaded npm/package.json
- src
  - node_modules // => shared modules for my project, not on npm
    - lib.ts
  - app.ts
- package.json
```

I have a secondary `node_modules` folder for my private packages mainly so I can import them from anywhere in my project and not have to worry about relative paths (as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24461606/399538)) on imports.

This works great because instead of `import * as lib from '../../lib'` or `var lib = require('../../lib')`, I can `import * as lib from 'lib'`.

Typescript compiles/loads `lib` w/o problem, but VS Code intellisense complains that it "cannot find module 'lib'".

FWIW, here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2015",
    "rootDir": "src"
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect this is because my shared/private modules don't have typings definitions... but these modules are also written in typescript. Is there any property in the `lib` module `package.json` that I could use to tell vscode/typescript that this is a typescript module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to modify the `package.json` of my `lib` to include a "typings" property:

```
{
  "name": "lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "lib.js",
  "typings": "lib"
}
```