# ES6 import with dynamic file name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

Is it possible to have a variable file name in the import syntax.

for example:

```
import * as myModule from "my-module";
```

to be something like this:

```
var module="my-module";
import * as myModule from module;
```

Or there is other approach for this? If not can you specify a base(root) dir from where to load the modules?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168433/es6-variable-import-name-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

For the baseroot I am just using a simple workaround with a symlink:

Link your src/ to the node_module/src

And use it:

`import A from 'src/some/where/A`

There are also other possible ways of doing it, but I am ok, with it, its really simple and it works ;)

Check out this [How to make the require in node.js to be always relative to the root folder of the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860244/how-to-make-the-require-in-node-js-to-be-always-relative-to-the-root-folder-of-t)