# Least verbose way of requiring a single file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, path, require

I'm using Node.js and want to split my code into separate files. However, it seems quite verbose to `require` these modules in a *reliable* way.

For example:

```
var module = require(path.resolve(__dirname, "./file.js"));
```

Furthermore, if the file is in a different folder, I'll need to deal with relative path mayhem.

It seems like quite a simple problem, but my research hasn't yielded a solution. Thanks for you time.

Comment: Why are relative paths unreliable? I've never run into an issue coding the relative path... `const module = require('../other_folder/file.js')`

Comment: @TJBlackman It is reliable, just very verbose. Without `path.resolve` and `__dirname`, you have to guarantee that the user is running the script in the correct folder. Relative paths can be annoying if you have a large tree, however.

Comment: @iONinja Relative paths (if they begin with `./`) are resolved _relative to the file they appear in._  The code shown in your question should behave identically to `var module = require('./file.js');` in all common cases.

Comment: @cdhowie, [thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50012690/5583289).

Comment: @iONinja No problem. Note that this is _not_ the case for "bare" paths, as in `require('file.js')`, which will only search the include folders (typically includes `node_modules` up the directory tree). `./` is the magic bit that tells `require()` that you want it to look relative to the directory containing the current module (and _only_ that directory -- include directories aren't searched).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Require paths are always relative to the script being run, so you don't need `path.resolve` or `__dirname`.

There are a [number of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10860244/5583289) for avoiding the inconvenience of relative paths.

Thanks [cdhowie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501250/cdhowie) for your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012548/least-verbose-way-of-requiring-a-single-file?noredirect=1#comment87041532_50012548).