# Relative path issue in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, commonjs

[image]

Above is the directory structure. I am trying to access the above highlighted file: DatabaseConnection using below code inside login_API.js

```
var connection = require("../../../../DatabaseConnection");
```

I am doing the same thing in many many other files.

Issue is: What will happen if the file path of DatabaseConnection is changes tomorrow. In that case I will have to rewrite the correct relative paths again in all the files.

Can you please suggest how can I change the above line of code to utilize it better?

I tried to follow an another way as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26163910/726802

But, failed to understand that how to use the below code in my case:

```
var myModule = require.main.require('./path/to/module');
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, `require.main.require()` cannot help you if the path of the required module is changed relatively to the root — it can help only if the path of the requiring module is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can place `DatabaseConnection.js` in `node_modules` and then require it this way:

```js
var connection = require("DatabaseConnection");
```

Comment: It is not safe to place this code in node_modules folder.

Comment: @Pankaj Maybe someone will be able to advise something else if you add some details in the question about why it is not safe to place the code in `node_modules` folder for your project.

Answer (score 0):

With nodejs you can use __filename or __dirname.
More information here, on the official site of Nodejs: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_filename