# Import JavaScript modules on client side : .js or mjs

Tags: javascript, module

When importing modules in JavaScript on client side, should the module extension be .js or .mjs?

```
import {myFunction, myVar} from './my_module.js'
// Or
import {myFunction, myVar} from './my_module.mjs'
```

The following question ([What is the difference between .js and .mjs files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57492546/what-is-the-difference-between-js-and-mjs-files)) is really interresting, but is focused on server-side (node.js). What about client side?

Comment: it's not a thing on the client side - use `.js` - besides, many HTTP servers would not send the right mime type for `.mjs` unless you configured them to

Comment: Exactly the answer I expected, one more time, Thank you Jaromanda. I'll upvote your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a file extension when you are dealing with HTTP. The `Content-Type` response header is used instead (and should be `application/javascript` just like any other JS).

You'll probably want use the `.js` file extension when serving static files since HTTP servers will tend to recognise it as JS so that is a convenient way to set the right `Content-Type` automatically.