# is it possible to get rid of the relative paths on imports?

Tags: react-native, expo

in any project with node.js, react, i set up the env variable:

```
NODE_PATH=src/
```

and then i can do imports like

```
import COLORS from 'Constants/Colors'
```

instead of

```
import COLORS from '../../../Constants/Colors'
```

I just started with react-native, with expo and am trying to find a solution for this.

I tried the same approach of adding the env variable and it doesn't work

Comment: You can use [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver) to use alias imports

Comment: @MahdiN, it worked! thank you. Can you please post it as an answer so i can upvote it and accepted as the solution?

Comment: Thank you man that's very cool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver) library to simplify your imports paths. It allows to write alias imports instead of complex relative paths.

Answer (score 2):

### Using the "Imports" property

As of March 2023, a good way to eliminate JavaScript relative paths is to use the `imports` property in `package.json`.  For more information, please refer to this post:

- [How to import JavaScript files in NodeJS using file paths from project root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75806206/how-to-import-javascript-files-in-nodejs-using-file-paths-from-project-root-in).

In the codes below, #root is the project root.

(Please kindly upvote this answer and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75806206/how-to-import-javascript-files-in-nodejs-using-file-paths-from-project-root-in) if they help you.  Thanks!)

### For CommonJS-style JavaScripts:

```js
// package.json
{
  "imports": {
    "#root/*.js": "./*.js"
  }
}

// main.js:
const Source = require('#root/path/to/Source.js');

// Source.js:
module.exports = class Source {
  // ...
}
```

### For ECMAScript-style JavaScripts:

```js
// package.json:
{
  "type" : "module",
  "imports": {
    "#root/*.js": "./*.js"
  }
}

// main.js
import { Source } from '#root/path/to/Source.js';

// Source.js:
export class Source {
  // ...
}
```

### Advantages:

- No need to "import" or "require" any additional packages (No Babel.js, No Webpack, No RequireJS).  After installing NodeJS, this method works out of the box.
- IDE linkages work as expected (Ctrl-click a class name to jump directly to the source file. Also, moving the source file (by drag and drop) will automatically update the file path references. Tested on `WebStorm 2022.3.2` and `VS Code 1.76.2`.)
- Works with both `.mjs` (ECMAScript module system) and `.cjs` (CommonJS) file types. Please see this [reference Post on .cjs and .mjs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57492546/what-is-the-difference-between-js-and-mjs-files)
- No need to modify with the reserved `node_modules` directory
- No need to set up any linux file links at the OS level

Answer (score 1):

install [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver) by

```
yarn add babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

then add relative path in `babel.config.js` file like this

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo', 'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset' ],
    plugins: [
            [
                'module-resolver',
                {
                    alias: {
                       '@company'     : './src/company.json',
                       '@components'     : './src/components'

                }
            }
            ]
        ]
  };
};
```

**then you can use an absolute path like this**

```
import TextLabel from './src/components/textLabel/index.js'
```

**To**

```
import TextLabel from '@components/textLabel/index.js'
```