# Import ES6 Modules with absolute paths in NodeJS without using Babel/Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, es6-modules

I have a plain old NodeJS project (with Typescript) and I'm really struggling to find out how to do ES6 imports for local files without having to do "../../../foo/bar" all the time.

There are loads of similar questions but all seem to revolve around babel/Webpack which I'm not using.

If I do the following:

```
import foo from `/bar`
```

it looks for it in the root folder of my PC (e.g. c:/bar) and fails.

I have tried using a .env file with NODE_PATH set to various hings ("/", "." etc) but no luck. I have also tried setting "type: 'module'" in my package.json and my tsconfig.json file has {"baseUrl": "."}

So I think I've tried every answer I can find. Am I just doing them in the wrong combination or is the solution something different?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: stackoverflow.com/a/78176236/11927087

Answer (score 9):

Here are two tricks I've used for this, with Node.js and native ES modules.

1. `file:` dependencies

If you want to access `<project root>/bar` from a sub package two levels down, adding this to the `package.json` dependencies:

```
    "@local/bar": "file:../../bar",
```

..makes `bar` available to the said subpackage as `@local/bar`.

While relative paths are still present, they are now all in the `package.json` files and the sources never need to know..

2. Use dynamic `import()`

Pick the root folder's path to a constant and do this:

```
const foo = await import(`${rootPath}/bar`);
```

Comment: Will dynamic importing result in that IDE lost some code intelligence?

Comment: @Jcyrss It might. I have successfully used alternative 1 now, for a while. It requires npm >= 7.7 but if that's okay, I recommend it. This reserves the dynamic import to cases that really need it.

Answer (score 7):

### Using the "Imports" property

As of March 2023, a good way to eliminate the NodeJS relative paths is to use the `imports` property in `package.json`.  For more information, please refer to this post:

- [How to import JavaScript files in NodeJS using file paths from project root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75806206/how-to-import-javascript-files-in-nodejs-using-file-paths-from-project-root-in).

In the codes below, #root is the project root.

(Please kindly upvote this answer and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75806206/how-to-import-javascript-files-in-nodejs-using-file-paths-from-project-root-in) if they help you.  Thanks!)

### For CommonJS-style JavaScripts:

```js
// package.json
{
  "imports": {
    "#root/*.js": "./*.js"
  }
}

// main.js:
const Source = require('#root/path/to/Source.js');

// Source.js:
module.exports = class Source {
  // ...
}
```

### For ECMAScript-style JavaScripts:

```js
// package.json:
{
  "type" : "module",
  "imports": {
    "#root/*.js": "./*.js"
  }
}

// main.js
import { Source } from '#root/path/to/Source.js';

// Source.js:
export class Source {
  // ...
}
```

### Advantages:

- No need to "import" or "require" any additional packages (No Babel.js, No Webpack, No RequireJS).  After installing NodeJS, this method works out of the box.
- IDE linkages work as expected (Ctrl-click a class name to jump directly to the source file. Also, moving the source file (by drag and drop) will automatically update the file path references. Tested on `WebStorm 2022.3.2` and `VS Code 1.76.2`.)
- Works with both `.mjs` (ECMAScript module system) and `.cjs` (CommonJS) file types. Please see this [reference Post on .cjs and .mjs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57492546/what-is-the-difference-between-js-and-mjs-files)
- No need to modify the reserved `node_modules` directory
- No need to set up any linux file links at the OS level

Comment: Should specify that the hash (#) is required here, it won't work without it as per the spec.

Answer (score 1):

This was pretty simple to implement for me, using Typescript in VSCode.

In `tsconfig.json`, I added `"baseUrl": "./",` under `compilerOptions`

After a restart of VSCode, VSCode will automatically import using psuedo-absolute paths.

The paths won't begin with `/`, that still points to your drive root.

If the is below the current file, it will still use a `./relative/path`, but no more `../../tree/traversing`

Then I set dev in packages.json to

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "dev": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./ nodemon ./app.ts"
},
```

I use `cross-env`. You may use the `set` command and `nodemon` for automatic reloading of change files.

Setting `NODE_PATH` to `./` tells NodeJS to do what Visual Studio and TypeScript are doing.

I do have `package.json` in my `src` directory. You may not, and may need to change some pathing to adjust.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you mean by "local files without having to do `"../../../foo/bar"`"

Let me explain how Javascript handles imports. Here is a basic folder structure.

```
C:Users/NAME/Project/randomfolder/bar.js


- Project
  - Random Folder
    - foo.js
  - bar.js
```

**Option 1** *Probably the better option for 95% of what you will do*

Let's say you are trying to import foo.js into bar.js we first get our current location of bar.js using a `.` so it would be

```
import foo from "./Random Folder/foo.js"
```

If you are going the other way the `.` is still used to say get current location in the folder structure but you pass a second `.` so `..` then a `/` to go up a folder. So to import bar.js into foo.js it would look like this:

```
import bar from "../bar.js"
```

We are going up a folder then looking for the file we want.

**Option 2**

But if you know you folder structure is going to be very big and you will be importing always a few folders up or down why not make a variable and then use string literals.

```
  let folder = `../../../`
  import test from `${folder}foo`
```

You have a few options of how to handle what you want to do.

**Option 3** *For NodeJS and modules*

If you are using NodeJS and want to get the path not relative, the use the [app-root-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-root-path) module. It lets you always get your project root and then dig into to files accordingly. This can be accomplished with string literals.

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
import foo from appRoot + "/foo/bar/folders/bla/bla"

or

import foo from `${appRoot}/foo/bar/folders/bla/bla` <-- string literals
```

Comment: Unfortunately both of these options still use relative urls, which means if I move my files to a different folder I have to update every single import. What I need is to be able to use the root of my project as the starting point (not the root of my hard drive), e.g. import foo from '/controllers/bar where the controllers folder is at the top level of my project. ' This would then work wherever I put my 'bar' file in the folder structure.

Comment: Since you are using NodeJS there is a package you can use called app-root-path: https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-root-path Then all you need to do is declare a variable for appRoot path and add it there.Will update my answer

Comment: How do you manage to make template literals work with `import` ? I get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected template string` when I try this syntax with Node 14.16.1. Interpolation works with the top-level await + dynamic import syntax but I find yours a lot more readable.