# Trying to use @local/package/name in package.json does not work, throws "name can only contain URL-friendly characters"

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I want to avoid using relative paths, and I found [this proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67128669/18051971), where you specify a `@local/package/name` pointed at `file:path/to/file`. I did not want to use Babel or something similar to address this issue, and so this seemed like a solid solution. I also found that they advertise this functionality [in the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#local-paths).

So ideally, instead of:

```
const FAClientManager = require("../../api/manager");
```

I can use, anywhere in my project:

```
const FAClientManager = require("@local/api/manager");
```

In my package.json, I set:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@local/api/manager": "file:./api/manager",
```

However, npm v8 is throwing this error when I try to use that package name:

> npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME npm ERR! Invalid package name
> "@local/api/manager" of package
> "@local/api/manager@file:./api/manager": name can only contain
> URL-friendly characters.

If I change the package name from `@local/api/manager` to `local/api/manager`, the same issue occurs. However if I also remove the slashes and make it `apimanager`, then it works. I don't want to use `apimanager` though, and I'd like to use the slashes for readability. I am importing other packages such as `@keyv/postgres` without issue, so why is it rejecting this file-based package?

The issue appears to occur if there's more than one slash, i.e. `@local/test` is good, but `@local/test/second` throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6333, you cannot nest that deep. So `@local/package` is your limit, and `@local/package/something` would throw the error being seen.

If you wanted to set a root path for reference throughout your project, you would add:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@local/self": "file:./",
```

And throughout your project, you could use at any level, for example:

```
require("@local/self/config.json");
```

Or for a module in a folder in your app directory, you could use at any level:

```
require("@local/self/some-module/path/module.js");
// or, of course:
// require("@local/self/some-module/path/module");
```

That way, instead of dealing with the `../../` relative imports and worrying when you move files around, you can just do a search and replace for `@local/self/some-module/path/module` with `@local/self/some-module/new/path/module`.

Comment: am searching, what would work for yarn