# Nodejs: use import in only one file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, es6-modules

I have a project which is build using require, but now I need to use a package @nfteyez/sol-rayz, which only have support for ES6 import.

I cannot add type: module because there are lots of files.

I have tried changing file to mjs, but I get errors when importing it with require in another file.

I found in example that is possible when you enable module you can use import with:

```
// Define "require"
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

is there something similar for import? I am using node v17

Comment: First of all you shouldn't use node v17 but LTS version. I don't know if I understood your question correctly. Is this what you want? https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm

Comment: @digitalniweb Thanks for your help, ESM did the trick. Please add your answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Go for dynamic `import()` function.

`let solRayz = await import('@nfteyez/sol-rayz');`

For complete suppression and use one common style, it is very difficult as the implicit packages have their own module system in their package files. For this particular problem, the following links might help

Complete flexibility of using module systems is not available as of now

[What is the difference between .js and .mjs files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57492546/what-is-the-difference-between-js-and-mjs-files)

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/esm.html#esm_differences_between_es_modules_and_commonjs

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js/

Answer (score -2):

in node.js v14 and above, we can enable es module support by just add this in `package.json`

```
"type": "module"
```