# Error with cannot use import statement outside of a module in isomorphic rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I've been getting an error saying I cannot use import statement outside of a module, I've set the package json in my backend folder to type module and don't believe I have a syntax error when I import app from my front end. What could be the issue?

This is my server.js -

```
import express from "express"
import React from 'react'
import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server'
import db from './db.js'
import App from '../frontend/src/App.js';
const app = express();



app.use(express.static('../frontend/public')); // added ../ to front end

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  
  const html = renderToString(React.createElement(App));
  res.send(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>My App</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <script src="/index.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
});

app.listen(8800, ()=> {
  console.log("Connected to backend!")
})
```

And this is my app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Footer, Contact, WhoChawewo, Header} from './containers';
import {Navbar, Background} from './components';
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

/* deleted div app */
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
   <Navbar />
    <Routes>
     
          <Route exact path='/' element={< Header />}> </Route>
          <Route path='/about' element={< WhoChawewo />}> </Route>
          <Route path='/contact' element={< Contact />}> </Route> 
   </Routes>
   <Footer/>

</BrowserRouter>


  )
}

export default App
```

I am not using any transpilers, could that be an issue or is there another way to achieve universal rendering

Comment: Browsers don't understand JSX so you're going to have to use a transpiler if you want to use JSX. The immediate error here is probably caused by this line `<script src="/index.js"></script>` and would go away if you changed it to `<script src="/index.js" type="module"></script>` but would probably just be replaced by a different parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already set `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, you can try explicitly annotating your files with the `.mjs` extension.

[What is the difference between .js and .mjs files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57492546/what-is-the-difference-between-js-and-mjs-files)

You can also try using Babel to transpile your code to older versions of JavaScript (https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: Yes I've done it, even used Babel to transpile but it all ends up with the same import syntax error. I cannot find an answer