# Node: Getting settings from application's package.json

Tags: node.js

I'm setting up a package to pull settings from the package.json of the application using the package. I'm currently doing that with this code:

```
var path = require('path');
var packageSettings = require(path.resolve('package.json'));
export default packageSettings.myPackage || {};
```

However, node/webpack throws this warning:
`Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`

I tried searching for a way to do this and had no luck. The documentation on `config` makes it sound like that applies only to scripts. Is this the best way to do this, or is there another?

Comment: `require('./package.json')`

Comment: And that's going to refer to package.json in the application using the package, not the package itself?

Comment: Yeah (if I understood the question), it will resolve the relative path with `__dirname`.

Comment: OK, but I want to put this code in my package so that I can inject configuration into the package. I want to get my package's settings from the application that uses it, or the global state if necessary.

Comment: Ah got it. No I don't know a way then. Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26163910/5378743 (But in the express boilerplate code for example, the entry point is not in the root folder, so not a robust solution)