# How to resolve relative path hell (node with typescript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, relative-path, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

I am developing a CLI using node, typescript and other packages. The idea is simple, the CLI gives you an initial structure for your node projects (javascript or typescript)

Well, while testing, I discovered a problem that I have not been able to solve for days. The initial structure is:

```
├────src
│    ├───api
│    │   └───users
│    │        ├───users.controller.ts/js
│    │        ├───users.interface.ts (just for typescript projects)
│    │        ├───users.routes.ts/js
│    │        └───users.service.ts/js
│    ├───config
│    │   └────environments
│    │        ├───development.ts/js
│    │        ├───index.ts/js
│    │        └───production.ts/js
│    ├───global
│    │   └───services
│    │        └───abstract.service.ts (just for typescript projects)
│    ├───middlewares
│    ├───database.ts/js
│    ├───index.ts/js
│    └───server.ts/js
├───.editorconfig
├───.env
├───.gitignore
├───package.json
├───package-lock.json
└───tsconfig.json (just for typescript projects)
```

The typescript services files extends of an abstract service (this one is in `./src/global/services/abstract.service.ts`). Each component will be in `./src/api` directory and have its respective folder (like users component). The relative path to import the abstract class in the users component is `../../global/services/abstract.service`

But you can create the component in a different directories, so the previous relative path does not work. To fix this problem I decided to using a routes configuration like webpack. So instead of use the previous relative path, I want to use something like this `@global/services/abstract.service`

I achieved this if the node project using javascript with babel:

- @babel/polyfill
- @babel/cli
- @babel/core
- @babel/node
- @babel/preset-node
- babel-plugin-module-resolver

But I don not achieved that when is a typescript project. The `tsconfig.json` has the "paths" options, this works in development, but when I compile typescript to javascript this doesn not work. I tried many ways to resolve that but everything failed. These are the packages that I've used until this now:

- link-module-alias ()
- ts-node with tsconfig-path
- ttypescript
- @zerollup/ts-transform-paths

The second one works correctly but I must restart for each changes that I make in ts files, maybe I did not configure the scripts correctly in `package.json`, because the tsc-watch did not work). The links I saw:

- [Require absolute instead of relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860244/how-to-make-node-js-require-absolute-instead-of-relative?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)
- [ttypescript](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript)
- [ts-transform-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zerollup/ts-transform-paths)
- [link-module-alias](https://medium.com/@kenichishibata/3-ways-to-fix-relative-paths-in-nodejs-require-ffc7f89bd7e1)
- [Relative path hell](https://arunmichaeldsouza.com/blog/aliasing-module-paths-in-node-js?fbclid=IwAR03IiP2CbKgfKTATlDggCsOyL3abRbT79p5LhwFqfT-WufDQGiG06_TrGs)
- [tsconfig paths](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/986)

Please, if anyone knows how to solve the **relative path hell**, I will appreciate it if you tell me how, with examples or something to help me

Comment: Just a google away... "typescript paths resolver" => https://github.com/duffman/tspath

Comment: As a workaround to the @Akxe comment [escaping relative path require hell in Node.js](https://www.coreycleary.me/escaping-relative-path-hell) and this [link](http://alexnj.com/blog/avoid-require-relativepath-hell-in-node-js/) as well.

Comment: I chose [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) for simplicity and effectiveness..