# Is it a bad idea to have Git repository in production server

Tags: git

We have a Windows Server 2012, Apache, PHP, and MySQL. The server is a bit a mess. One of the things that I want is to track the changes on the code. Normally I don't set up Git on the server, instead I develop on the local machine then using SSH I deploy changes to the production server. However this Windows Server 2012 was not set up by me and thus it is a bit mess. I cannot copy the PHP code and develop it in my machine because it runs on PHP 5.2 and the code is encrypted. Thus, I think I have to set up Git in the production server.

I wonder, then will there be performance problems?

Comment: Why do you think putting git on a server will affect server performance? Just don't put the .git folder anywhere publicly accessible, but that's nothing to do with performance.

Comment: @AD7six, a year ago I was trying to setup Git on our Linux server, and the sysadmin was telling my employer that it might have performance issues.

Comment: Well, he was full of it =), or there's something more to that story. That's not to say deploying with git is a "good" thing (it's not "bad" it's just not the best solution in many cases), but it only puts a folder on the server that you don't directly access.

Answer (score 4):

It's standard practice everywhere to deploy from a git (or at least some form of version control) repository, but the method of doing the deploy is pretty much whatever you feel like.

If you have workspaces/folders that store each version that has been deployed, it's fine to just push up your working copy to production.

One pattern is to tag your releases with git and check those out directly (`git checkout v1.0.0`) on the server, or to use a git hosting server's facilities to download a tarball of your tag.

For example, you can download a tarball of the tag `v1.0.0` from github like so:

```
https://github.com/<user>/<project>/archive/v1.0.0.tar.gz
```

There's no performance overhead to running a single (or many; checked out working copies introduce no overhead) git repo on a windows server, but be careful not to expose the `.git` folder if you clone directly.

Also, never force push to your `master` (or equivalent) branch, or you're asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

No, I think not Heroku servers are fine with github, but push carefully and work on branches not on master directly.

Comment: Well, the working environment is the production server itself since 2013, and I cannot run the code outside, so it will stay same. Actually it is a finished product. We do only maintenance and sometime we develop independent modules.

Comment: In any case push your work with SSH or with git is exactly the same; git uses SSH keys.