# How to detect if webpack-dev-server is running?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

How can I determine if `webpack.config.js` was loaded via `webpack` vs `webpack-dev-server`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Update**: The environment variable is [changed](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/3000) to `WEBPACK_SERVE`.

The webpack dev server [will now](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/1929) set the `WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER` environment variable, allowing for a more robust way to check.

```
const isDevServer = process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER;
```

Comment: Both of these are undefined for me in Webpack 5.58.1 with `devServer` enabled in the config.

Comment: `main.js:367 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined` However, process.env.NODE_ENV is working. Not sure why?

Comment: Seems this env var is always true...

Answer (score 19):

Either:

`const isDevServer = process.argv[1].indexOf('webpack-dev-server') !== -1;`

or:

`const isDevServer = process.argv.some(v => v.indexOf('webpack-dev-server') !== -1);`

or:

`const isDevServer = process.argv.some(v => v.includes('webpack-dev-server'));`

I've been using the latter to a great effect. One configuration FTW!

Comment: or... `const isDevServer = process.argv.find(v => v.includes('webpack-dev-server'))`

Comment: One nitpick: the 2nd and 3rd options will actually set `isDevServer` to the value of the `argv` element that contained `'webpack-dev-server'`. Substitute `some` for `find` to ensure `isDevServer` is a boolean.

Comment: @lawnsea just seen this and you're right, `some` would be better. I've edited my answer and thank you :)

Comment: @bjfletcher `main.js:367 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined` However, process.env.NODE_ENV is working. Not sure why?

Answer (score 7):

I found one potential soluton:

```
var isDevServer = path.basename(require.main.filename) === 'webpack-dev-server.js';
```

[credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18721515/65387)

Comment: I like this answer more. Alternatively you can do: `path.relative('', require.main.filename) == 'node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js'`.

Answer (score 6):

Or use the [Webpack Environment Variables](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables):

```
// The webpack command line
webpack-dev-server --open --env.devServer

// webpack.config.js
module.exports = env => {
  console.log('isDevServer: ', env.devServer) // true
  ...
}
```

Comment: can you leverage that so that you only start the webpack dev server IF it's not already started?

Answer (score -1):

In general, `webpack-dev-server` runs with `mode='development'` (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/#root), while `webpack` runs with `mode=production`. If so, you can use the value of:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```