# app-root-path doesn't return absolute path correctly on linux?

Tags: linux, node.js, windows, path

I'm building an os-agnostic `npm` package that uses a few submodules from within itself. On my mac, I `require` modules using [app-root-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-root-path) like so:

```
var path = require('path');
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');

var packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(appRoot.path, 'node_modules', 'myModule', 'package.json')).toString());
```

and this works as expected.

But it fails on linux (and I assume it'd fail on windows too) because the `app-root-path` package above doesn't return correct path the same way it does on mac.

```
return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/myModule/bin/node_modules/myModule/package.json'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:431:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/myModule/bin/commands.js:247:33)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:138:18)
```

Why is this?

How can I make it work without worrying about host OS (mac / linux / windows)?

Note, I did use the answers/tips on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265798/determine-project-root-from-a-running-node-js-application) on stackoverflow.