# Where to store a node_package specific settings on the client machine?

Tags: node.js, npm, dotfiles

I' have a node_package [bookiza](http://bookiza.io) (installed globally) that POSTS/PATCHes values to a receiving substrate using credentials taken off a .rc file.

I'm currently saving the `.rc` file inside the module itself, at `usr/lib/node_modules/bookiza`, but I can do so anywhere I like. The problem in storing it inside the package is that the settings are overwritten whenever the user `npm i -g installs` again, to update the package.

```
function updateBookizaConfig(res) {

  var bookizaConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', '.bookizarc')).toString());

  bookizaConfig.token = res.body.key;
  bookizaConfig.username = res.body.username;
  bookizaConfig.email = res.body.email;

  fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', '.bookizarc'), JSON.stringify(bookizaConfig, null, 2));

  // Move or copy the config file outside of package to retain credentials upon package update.
  // cp('-R', path.join(__dirname, '..', '.bookizarc'), path.join(__dirname, '..', '..')); 

  console.log(chalk.bold.cyan('Registration successful'));

}
```

This works, but note that the `.dotfile` file is saved inside `usr/lib/node_modules/` directory, as a sibling to other global packages installed on the machine. Now I could put the settings file anywhere else on the machine too, but what is the good practice/standard way of doing this?

Will it be better for me to put the settings file inside a `usr/lib/node_modules/dots` folder where in future other package writers could also probably put their .rc files?

Comment: each OS has different locations. If you're talking `usr/lib`, stop think of Unix only immediately, and instead find yourself a module (that someone else already wrote) that gets you the write location for application data. Then use that. Why would you intentionally break cross-platform compatibility? It's a node module; unless you're doing low level native OS or hardware specific things, your code is supposed to be universal.

Comment: I agree. The module/CLI I have up here is OS-agnostic, that *is* why node. Using another module like? This may sound a little sacrilegious but it's not so easy to find cross-platform packages that work. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072572/app-root-path-doesnt-return-absolute-path-correctly-on-linux

Comment: npmjs.com, search "appdata". First hit? https://www.npmjs.com/package/appdirectory -- sounds like we found your module. Alternative? https://www.npmjs.com/package/user-settings-dir, a few hits down. Finding modules is actually *really* easy. We dig a little further because people say "...based on..." and end up with https://www.npmjs.com/package/os-homedir, which gets *4.5 million downloads* a month. We found the winning module.

Comment: :) Thanks Mike! Looks like I was going about this search with wrong keywords. This is exactly what I have been looking for days!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users in the comments have already hit on this solution, but here for the record anyway:

1. npm recommends you save user-specific config data in the user's home directory rather than in npm's modules directory, both because it is inconvenient to persist those settings, and because it is a problem in multi-user environments.
2. There are a number of modules that will find the user's home directory in a cross-platform way for you to put your files in; we like https://www.npmjs.com/package/osenv