# Write a file to a directory which is different from working directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have my project structure something like this

[image]

Now, I need to write a file from assets.js to a file in pdf folder.

That is what i am trying

```
var qrImgPath =   '/lib/pdf/' +eod+'.png';
                    fs.writeFile(qrImgPath,body,'binary',function(err){
                        return next();
                    });
```

but i am getting following error

```
{ handle: 2,
  type: 'error',
  className: 'Error',
  constructorFunction: { ref: 5 },
  protoObject: { ref: 6 },
  prototypeObject: { ref: 1 },
  properties: 
   [ { name: 'stack',
       attributes: 2,
       propertyType: 3,
       ref: 1 },
     { name: 'arguments',
       attributes: 2,
       propertyType: 1,
       ref: 1 },
     { name: 'type',
       attributes: 2,
       propertyType: 1,
       ref: 1 },
     { name: 'message',
       attributes: 2,
       propertyType: 1,
       ref: 7 },
     { name: 'errno',
       propertyType: 1,
       ref: 8 },
     { name: 'code',
       propertyType: 1,
       ref: 9 },
     { name: 'path',
       propertyType: 1,
       ref: 10 } ],
  text: 'Error: ENOENT, open \'/lib/pdf/b0551796a741aa885e641dbd895a233f.png\'' }
```

.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Use a relative path, like so: `var qrImgPath =   '../../lib/pdf/' +eod+'.png';`

Comment: @JonathanBrooks still same error

Comment: This error means `/lib/pdf/b0551796a741aa885e641dbd895a233f.png` does not exist. You can run `fs.existsSync('/lib/pdf/b0551796a741aa885e641dbd895a233f.png')` to test for its existance.

Comment: if  i am not wrong fs.writeFile creates the file if does not exists. my problem is fs is  not able to switch directory from "routes" to "lib"  where i wants to write the file

Comment: @AtulAgrawal Correct. But it can't create the file with missing parent folders. Make sure that the path is correct.

Comment: parent folder is there as you can see in my screen shot of project structure.As i said in last comment i am not able to switch from one directory to other

Comment: Your path is incorrect because the `root` path is missing. The correct one should be something similar to `ROOT_DIR + '/lib/pdf/b0551796a741aa885e641dbd895a233f.png'`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265798/determine-project-root-from-a-running-node-js-application) for more information about defining root directory.

Comment: Please see krakig's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__dirname`. (https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)

```
path.join(__dirname, "../../lib/pdf" + eod + "png");
```

Comment: No success and i am getting Error: ENOENT, open \'/home/atul/Workplace/market-invoice/routes../../lib/pdfb0551796a741aa885e641dbd895a233fpng\

Comment: got some error . but after resolving those error working fine. thanks

Comment: path is a library, you need to get it from npm

Comment: I have already imported that .No this is because of relative path  '../../lib/pdf'  and please don't forget to upvote my question . thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

You could use the __dirname global variable, that returns the name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in.

So, your code should be something like:

```
var qrImgPath =   path.join(__dirname, '../lib/pdf/' +eod+'.png');
                    fs.writeFile(qrImgPath,body, 'binary',function(err){
                        return next();
                    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately no success

Comment: this is what i am getting                                                                           Error: ENOENT, open \'/home/atul/Workplace/market-invoice/routes/lib/pdf/b0551796a741aa885e641dbd895a233f.png\'

Comment: Change this line: var qrImgPath =   '../../lib/pdf/' +eod+'.png';

Comment: Error: ENOENT, open \'/home/atul/Workplace/market-invoice/routes../../lib/pdf/b0551796a741aa885e641dbd895a233f.png\'

Comment: Man __dirname returns the current directory which is '/home/atul/Workplace/market-invoice/routes and when i add my path it does not change the directory. i need something like this '/home/atul/Workplace/market-invoice/lib/pdf ' which is the actual path where i need to write my file

Comment: You're right... see my edit, using path.join should work fine