# Can the required path be from project root and not relative?

Tags: node.js

I worry that if my requiring module changes path I would need to update all required path!! (A thing that would not happen in java)

MyModule.js
require('./lib')

Now MyModule changes directory now I need to do

```
require('../../lib')
```

Anyway to specify require path as from project root?

```
require('/lib')
```

I'm writing this from my mobile sorry if I lack formatting

Comment: You can't do that.  Consider making separate npm packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265798/determine-project-root-from-a-running-node-js-application?rq=1

Comment: @Slaks I would but those are really internals to my project I like them part of my project.   This feature sounds so basic for me coming from java I don't get how it's not out of the box.

Comment: @Slaks I would like to accept your answer.  I'm not going for a separate npm package because these `js` modules are really internal to my project.  In addition I would not want to clutter my global OS `NODE_PATH` because  If I have multiple node projects starting up they would each override the others NODE_PATH.  which means in my case I just can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before running your node app, first run:

```
Linux: export NODE_PATH=.
Windows: set NODE_PATH=.
```

You could add it in the npm start script itself so, you  can automate it easily.

**EXAMPLE:**

***`Directory tree`:***

```
my_example/
├── lib
│   ├── a
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── b
│       └── index.js
├── package.json
└── server.js
```

**File Contents:**

***`package.json`***:

```
{
  *
  *
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export NODE_PATH=./lib/;node server.js"
  },
  *
  *
}
```

***`./lib/a/index.js`***:

```
console.log("hi from module a");
require("b/index");
```

***`./lib/b/index.js`***:

```
console.log("hi from module b");
```

***`./server.js`***:

```
require("a/index");
```

OUTPUT on running `npm start`:

```
hi from module a
hi from module b
```

Comment: Would this mean other developers need to run non start when they work on my project? Also if I toggle between node projects I would need to reset this parameter?

Comment: when u put it in npm start, then everytime it is run, it will automatically set it before node is run, and pesists for the opened shell and dies after.

Comment: @Jas have made an edit to include full example with full details.