# Is there a way to get the package.json properties in a module run from npm?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, package.json

I'm writing a module will will be run from a "scripts" property like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "runMyModule": "mymodule -stuff stuff"
}
```

**NOTE: This is not the `package.json` of my module. This is the `package.json` the user uses to run npm.**

I want to allow them to add a property to that main `package.json` file (which at the command line they execute by `npm run runMyModule`) which my module will then read. Is this possible?

I want something like:

```
"forMyModule": {
    stuff: [
        "one",
        "two"
    ]
},

"scripts": {
    "runMyModule": "mymodule -stuff stuff"
}
```

Is it possible in my module to get the `forMyModule.stuff`?

I've created both the `index.js` and `bin/mymodule.js` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the root path of the project that uses your module. There are several ways to do this, each with its pros and cons: [Determine project root from a running node.js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265798/determine-project-root-from-a-running-node-js-application)

Once you have that path, you can simply `require(path.join([rootPath, 'package.json']))` and inspect the contents to find the settings.

Comment: Thank you. I used the link and your suggested code to use `var settings = require( process.cwd() + "/package.json" );`

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
var pjson = require('../package.json');
console.log(pjson.forMyModule);
```

Comment: I believe so? Globally installed modules have the same directory layout inside a node_modules/ directory, just with a different path (global) prefix.

Comment: Not work on every case, using webpack, you can get a error:
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../package which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.