# NodeJS: How to get absolut path - as 'path' is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, path

In my nodeJS application (meteorJS) I need to use an absolut path for creating a file via `fs.createWriteStream`:

```
const absolutePath = '/Users/Anybody/Documents/Project/imports/temp'
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  const result = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const gfs = Grid(
      MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db,
      MongoInternals.NpmModule
    )
    const readerStream = gfs.createReadStream({ _id: id })
    const writerStream = fs.createWriteStream(absolutePath + 'temp.mp4')
    // ...
  })
}
```

This is how the code looks like for development, which I do on macOS. The production version of the application is deployed to an ubuntu server.
So the absolute path is different.

I tried to use `path`:

```
const path = require('path')
const absolutePath = path.resolve('/imports/temp')
```

But this gives me only `/imports/temp` (on macOS)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine project root from a running node.js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265798/determine-project-root-from-a-running-node-js-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use process.env.PWD to get your base path of you project. Then you can add your remaining folder segment path.

```
var base = process.env.PWD;
const absolutePath = base + '/imports/temp';
```