# Why does __dirname does not return an absolute directory path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, dirname

I am trying to read a file with `fs.readFileSync` and I'm running into some issues locating that file with `__dirname`. This is my directory structure:

```
/Users
  /me
    /Documents
      /myapp
        /services
          /myapp (node app here)
            /server
              /templates
                /docx
                 -word2016_tpl.docx
              /methods
                /documents
                 -fetchDocument.ts
```

I am trying to read the file `word2016_tpl.docx` from `fetchDocument.ts`. When I read the file as a static string, everything works perfectly. Like so:

```
const buff = fs.readFileSync(
'/Users/me/Documents/myapp/services/myapp/server/templates/docx/word2016_tpl.docx'
);
```

However, clearly the above is not a good practice so I am trying to dynamically generate the file path using `__dirname`.

In `fetchDocument.ts`, I have:

```
console.log('current directory: ', __dirname);

// current directory:  /server/methods/documents
```

My question is, where is the preceeding `/Users/me/Documents/myapp/services/myapp/` and how do I access it?

Edit:

I've also tried reading the file with `fs.readFileSync('/server/templates/docx/word2016_tpl.docx')` and that doesn't work

Comment: You can just type `DriveName:/Rest of the path`, can’t you?

Comment: by DriveName do you mean `/Users/me/Documents/myapp/services/myapp/`? if so, I don't want to statically write that because I don't think that would work in production

Comment: Usually people have `C:` or `D:` or `E:`

Comment: am I misunderstanding how `__dirname` works? From reading other stackoverflow questions it seems like it's supposed to return the entire path. I'm on a mac so my path starts with `/Users/me`

Comment: I’ve never actually used that so I would actually be taught from this question

Comment: Not sure if it has something to do with Mac, but normally it should always return absolute path. Try resolving with path `const path = require('path');
const check = path.resolve(__dirname, './');`

Comment: just tried this, and console.log(check) returns `/server/methods/documents` as well :(

Comment: @MrMythical thats a windows convention, not universal.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question/answer:
[Determine project root from a running node.js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265798/determine-project-root-from-a-running-node-js-application)

I was able to resolve my issue by getting the root path using `process.env.PWD` and joining that with the relative path `/server/templates/docx/word2016_tpl.docx`

aka

```
const absolutePath = path.join(appRoot, relativePath);
const buff = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath);
```

Hopefully this works. I've read there are a couple of problems with `process.env.PWD` such as it does not work on the windows OS. Any comments here would be appreciated!