# Is it possible to get project name via global variable in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Currently I use two global variables (`__filename`, `__dirname`) of `node.js`. Now in my code I need to get the name of the project. Is it possible to get via `node.js` global variable? Note: I can't directly `import package.json` as this is a browser application with `webpack`.

Comment: You can import `package.json` just fine – Webpack will bundle it.

Comment: I don't think there's a global variable but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265798/determine-project-root-from-a-running-node-js-application) will help you