# simplifying getting root directory

Tags: node.js

I have the following folder structure

```
public
source
  client
    config
      webpack.common.js
```

inside the weback.common.js I want to reference the public folder

```
path.resolve(__dirname, '../', '../', '../', 'public')
```

it works but it's very annoying and long, is there is a better way to reference this folder ?

Comment: `path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../public')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine project root from a running node.js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265798/determine-project-root-from-a-running-node-js-application)